# How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?

Tags: shell, sed, freebsd, gnu, portability

I'm writing shell scripts for my server, which is a shared hosting running FreeBSD. I also want to be able to test them locally, on my PC running Linux. Hence, I'm trying to write them in a portable way, but with `sed` I see no way to do that.

Part of my website uses generated static HTML files, and this sed line inserts correct DOCTYPE after each regeneration:

```
sed -i '1s/^/<!DOCTYPE html> \n/' ${file_name.html}
```

It works with GNU `sed` on Linux, but FreeBSD `sed` expects the first argument after `-i` option to be extension for backup copy. This is how it would look like:

```
sed -i '' '1s/^/<!DOCTYPE html> \n/' ${file_name.html}
```

However, GNU `sed` in turn expects the expression to follow immediately after `-i`.
(It also requires fixes with newline handling, but that's already answered in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42321/how-can-i-instruct-bsd-sed-to-interpret-escape-sequences-like-n-and-t/42330))

Of course I can include this change in my server copy of the script, but that would mess i.e. my use of VCS for versioning. Is there a way to achieve this with sed in a fully portable way?

Comment: The two sed snippets you provided are identical, are you sure there isn't a typo? Also, i am able to execute GNU sed supplying the backup extension right after `-i`

Comment: Duh, thanks for spotting this. I've fixed my question. The second line results in error in my sed, it expects '1s/^/<!DOCTYPE html> \n/' to be a file and complains it can't find it.

Comment: Cross reference: [sed in-place flag that works both on Mac (BSD) and Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5694228/1468366) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

GNU sed accepts an optional extension after `-i`. The extension must be in the same argument with no intervening space. This syntax also works on FreeBSD sed.

```
sed -i.bak -e '…' SOMEFILE
```

Note that on FreeBSD, `-i` also changes the behavior when there are multiple input files: they are processed independently (so e.g. `$` matches the last line of each file). Also this won't work on BusyBox.

If you don't want to use backup files, you could check which version of sed is available.

```
# Assume that sed is either FreeBSD/macOS or GNU
case $(sed --help 2>&1) in
  *GNU*) set sed -i;;
  *) set sed -i '';;
esac
"$@" -e '…' "$file"
```

Or alternatively, to avoid clobbering the positional parameters, define a function.

```
case $(sed --help 2>&1) in
  *GNU*) sed_i () { sed -i "$@"; };;
  *) sed_i () { sed -i '' "$@"; };;
esac
sed_i -e '…' "$file"
```

If you don't want to bother, use Perl.

```
perl -i -pe '…' "$file"
```

If you want to write a portable script, don't use `-i` — it isn't in POSIX. Do manually what sed does under the hood — it's only one more line of code.

```
sed -e '…' "$file" >"$file.new"
mv -- "$file.new" "$file"
```

Comment: GNU `sed -i` also implies `-s`. And the easiest way to check for a GNU `sed` is with the `sed v` command which is a valid noop for GNU but fails everywhere else.

Comment: Inspired by the above tips, here's an single-line (if ugly) portable version for those who really want one, though it does spawn a subshell: `sed -i$(sed v < /dev/null 2> /dev/null || echo -n " ''") -e '...' "$file"` If it's not GNU sed, it inserts a space followed by two singe quotes after `-i` so that it works on BSD. GNU sed gets only `-i`.

Comment: @IvanX I'm wary of using the presence of the `v` command to test for GNU sed. What if FreeBSD decided to implement it?

Comment: @Gilles Fair point, but the man page for GNU sed describes v as being exactly for that purpose (detecting that it's GNU sed and not something else), so one would hope that *BSD would honor that. I can't think of another test, offhand, that takes no action on GNU sed, while causing an error on BSD sed (or vice versa), other than using -i itself, but that would require creating a dummy file first. Your test for sed above is OK but unwieldy for inline. Avoiding -i entirely, as you suggest, certainly seems like the safest bet, but I'm ok with using `sed v` given that's its purpose for existing.

Comment: The trick with `"$@"` is very nice, but I wouldn't use it in a longer script. Unfortunately normal variables are not expanded in that way (and `sh` doesn't have arrays) so I couldn't find anything better.

Comment: @lapo An alternative is to define a function, see my edit.

Comment: For portability, perl in-place editing is a better answer than sed.  The -i (GNU extension) is not POSIX as Gilles stated, and Perl doesn't need any special module or extension to perform this operation.

Comment: Not sure when it changed, but busybox 1.32 supports '-i.bak' just fine

Comment: It's not GNU vs BSD, it's GNU/NetBSD/OpenBSD/busybox/toybox vs FreeBSD/macos.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't find a trick to make `sed` play nice, you could try:

1. Don't use `-i` :

   ```
   sed '1s/^/<!DOCTYPE html> \n/' "${file_name.html}" > "${file_name.html}.tmp" &&
     mv "${file_name.html}.tmp" "${file_name.html}"
   ```
2. Use Perl

   ```
   perl -i -pe 'print "<!DOCTYPE html> \n" if $.==1;' "${file_name.html}"
   ```

Answer (score 9):

#### ed

You can always use `ed` to prepend a line to an existing file.

```
$ printf '0a\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n.\nw\n' | ed my.html
```

#### Details

The bits around the `<!DOCTYPE html>` are commands to `ed` instructing it to add that line to the file `my.html`.

#### sed

I believe this command in `sed` can also be used:

```
$ sed -i '1i<!DOCTYPE html>\n` testfile.csv
```

Comment: I eventually resorted to Perl, but using ed is a good alternative that's not popular among Unix-like users as it should be.

Comment: @Red - glad to hear you resolved you issue. Yeah I'd not seen that one before, googling turned it up and it actually seemed like the most portable, apt way to do this.

Answer (score 8):

You can also do manually what `perl -i` used to do under the hood:

```
{ rm -f file && { echo '<!DOCTYPE html>'; cat; } > file;} < file
```

Like `perl -i`, there's no backup, and like most solutions given here, beware it may affect the permissions, ownership of the file and may turn a symlink into a regular file.

With:

```
sed '1i\
<!DOCTYPE html>' file 1<> file
```

`sed` would overwrite the file over itself, so would not affect ownership and permissions or symlinks. It works with GNU `sed` because `sed` will typically have read a buffer full of data from `file` (4k in my case) before overwriting it with the `i` command. That wouldn't work if the file was more than 4k except for the fact that `sed` also buffers its output.

Basically `sed` works on blocks of 4k for reading and writing. If the line to insert is smaller than 4k, `sed` will never overwrite a block it has not read yet.

I wouldn't count on it though.

Beware that with all those solutions, if the file system is full or the system crashes in the middle, you may end up losing data.

Comment: Should be `echo '<!DOCTYPE html>'` or escaped without "" quotes.

Comment: @A.D. Good point. I tend to forget about that bug^Wfeature of interactive bash/zsh as I generally disable it for myself.

Comment: This is one of the *very* few answers here that doesn't have a wide open security hole of redirecting to a "temp file" with a static, predictable name without checking if it already exists.  I believe this should be the accepted answer.  Very nice demonstration of the use of group commands, also.

Comment: I really like this. As to losing permissions (which `perl -i` preserves), one could `stat -c %a` before the `rm` and then `chmod` before the close brace. But not only are you then getting into ugly code territory, you'd also need to consider that a setgid bit on the original file may not be desirable on the new one since the group may have changed.

Comment: If the system crashes (or the command gets prematurely terminated) while you’re running `sed -i`, do you totally lose your file? (It’s my understanding that it writes output to a new (temporary) file, *and **then*** deletes the input file and renames the output file, as simulated in [terdon’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92896/80216).) The above command is vulnerable to interruption, unless I’m overlooking something.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', I've  not checked all `sed` implementations, but yes, IIRC GNU sed tries to create a new file with the same metadata (which terdon's doesn't do, he's got missing `--`s which could end up being problematic as well (even ACE vulnerabiity in GNU sed), and could clobber an existing file.tmp) and replace the original in the end (but breaks symlinks IIRC). perl -i last I checked (many years ago, it might have changed since), behaves like my rm+cat, and yes could lose data. But then again, all sorts of things can be lost upon system crash.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', from strace, it looks like perl now behaves like GNU `sed` and writes to a new temp file. It does copy some metadata (which my cat+rm doesn't even try to do either)

Answer (score 3):

FreeBSD [sed](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/master/usr.bin/sed), which is used on Mac OS X as well, needs the `-e` option after the `-i` switch to define & recognise the following (regex) command correctly & unambiguously.

In other words, `sed -i -e ...` should work with both FreeBSD & GNU `sed`.

More generally, omitting the backup extension after FreeBSD `sed -i` requires some explicit `sed` option or switch following the `-i` to avoid confusion on part of FreeBSD `sed` while parsing its command-line arguments.

(Note, however, that `sed` in-place file edits lead to file inode changes, see ["In-place" editing of files](http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/)).

(As a general hint, recent versions of FreeBSD `sed` have the `-r` switch to increase compatibility with GNU `sed`).

```
echo a > testfile.txt
ls -li testfile.txt
#gsed -i -e 's/a/A/' testfile.txt
#bsdsed -i 's/a/A/' testfile.txt  # does not work
bsdsed -i -e 's/a/A/' testfile.txt
ls -li testfile.txt
cat testfile.txt
```

Comment: No, `bsdsed -i -e 's/a/A/'` is _not_ in-place editing, it's editing with saving the original with a "-e" suffix (`testfile.txt-e`).

Comment: note that GNU sed also supports -E (in addition to -r) for compatibility with FreeBSD. -E is likely to be specified in the next POSIX version, so we should all be forgetting about that -r non-sense and pretend it never existed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```bsh
ex -s -c '1i|<!DOCTYPE html>' -c x file
```

1. `1` select first line
2. `i` insert text and newline
3. `x` save and close

Comment: There's nothing Vim-specific here.  This is fully compliant with [POSIX specifications for `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html), except that implementations are not *required* to support multiple `-c` flags.  For definite portability I would use `printf '%s\n' 1i '<!DOCTYPE html>' . x | ex file`

Answer (score 1):

To emulate `sed -i` for a single file portably while avoiding race conditions as much as possible:

```
sed 'script' <<FILE >file
$(cat file)
FILE
```

By the way, this also handles the possible problem that `sed -i` introduces in that, depending on directory and file permissions, `sed -i` might enable a user to overwrite a file which that user does not have permissions to edit.

You might also do backups like:

```
sed 'script' <<FILE >file
$(tee file.old <file)
FILE
```