# How can I get my sed command to make permanent changes to a file?

Tags: sed

Is this possible? I read somewhere that the following command would do it:

> sed -e [command] [file]

but it appeared to do the same thing as just

> sed [command] [file]

(it did not save the changes). Is there any way to do this using sed?

Comment: The `-e` flag stands for expression. You probably want the `-i` flag  which means `in-place` and I strongly recommend you to use  `sed -i.bak 's/../' filename`

Answer (score 67):

I think you are looking for `-i`:

```
   -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

          edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

For example:

```
$ cat foo.txt
hello world
$ sed -i 's/o/X/g' foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt
hellX wXrld
```

If you provide a suffix, it will create a backup file:

```
$ ls
foo.txt
$ sed -i.bak 's/o/X/g' foo.txt 
$ ls
foo.txt  foo.txt.bak
```

The input file is modified and a backup containing the original file data is created.

Also note that this is for GNU `sed`, there are [slight differences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92895/22222) in format between different `sed` implementations.

Comment: Note that the man page is wrong. `sed` does not do in-place editing. It creates a new file and overwrites the old one, the inode changes.

Comment: @Marco That's the safe way of editing a file in place. “Editing a file in place” in the sed documentation means that the original file (as defined by its name) is modified, not that the original file (as defined by its inode) is modified.

Comment: @Gilles I totally agree that this is the preferred way to edit a file, but I'd hardly call it *in-place*. But that boils down to the question of how a file is identified, by inode or by name. I would say by inode, otherwise contructs like `{ rm file; cmd > file; } < file` would lead to the conclusion that cmd reads and writes to the same file, which it does not. It's two distince files which just happen to have the same name. But I don't want to start a discussion here.

Comment: On macOS 10.14 I get `sed: 1: "foo.txt": invalid command code f` when running `sed -i 's/o/X/g' foo.txt`. However, providing an extension, like `sed -i .bak 's/o/X/g' foo.txt` works fine. Any ideas how to get it working without creating backup files?

Comment: Okay, figured it out. In macOS you need to explicitly add an empty string for the extension param option: `sed -i '' 's/o/X/g' foo.txt`

Comment: @JoshuaPinter yes, BSD sed (which is what macOS uses) needs that. See the "slight differences" link at the end of my answer for more details.

Comment: @terdon Great, thanks. I must have missed that link on the first go 'round.

Answer (score 2):

These solution works for HPUX (UNIX):

1.
`{ rm test1.sh && awk '{gsub("Error", "NO_Error", $0); print}' > test1.sh; } < test1.sh`:

2.
`perl -pi -e 's/Error/NO_Error/g' test1.sh`

3.
`sed 's/Error/NO_Error/g' test1.sh | tee test1.sh`

Comment: You cannot use tee http://askubuntu.com/a/752451

Answer (score 2):

`-e` option is for executing multiple `sed` commands

```
sed -e 's/linux/unix/' -e 's/os/OS/' file.txt
```

consider `file.txt` as

```
linux os
```

then O/P is

```
unix os
```

`-i` option saves changes permanently...