# sed + replace string in Square brackets with key

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want with sed to replace what is in [….]  with target `key=new_string`

```
more /tmp/file
my.uri=http://[linux123]:8080
```

we try this

```
key=new_string

sed  s"/\[*\]/$key/g" /tmp/file
```

but file not changed

```
more file
my.uri=http://[linux123]:8080
```

what is wrong with my sed?

Expected results should be ( without Square brackets )

```
more file
my.uri=http://new_string:8080
```

Comment: This post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/95884/how-can-i-get-my-sed-command-to-make-permanent-changes-to-a-file describes how to do the change in-place, but also your sed command needs to be fixed. You have to match an opening bracket, any character not being a closing bracket, and to a closing bracket. And the replacement part should include the brackets too.

Comment: see my update , its should be without [  ]

Comment: Then the replacement pattern is good, just the variable, the matching pattern needs to be `\[[^]]*\]`. This is a regular expression, to be used in sed. If you had a star alone instead of `[^]]*` it would be a shell glob expression (matching anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to ensure that your `key` variable does not contain any characters with special meaning for your `sed` command, like for example `/` which is the default separating character for the sed substitution. In such a case you could use a different character, for example like this `"s@pattern@replacement@g" file`.

Then you need to match from an opening until the corresponding closing bracket. That would be `\[.*\]` but sed is greedy: In case your line contains `[text1] text2 [text3]`, sed will match all of this. So you need to define, instead of `.*`, any character which is not a closing bracket, zero or more times: `[^]]*`.

Note that in the above, we don't need to escape (`\]`) the bracket in the middle, because `sed` awaits for at least one character to exclude after the caret (`^`), so it will not misread this as the closing bracket of the list of the excluded characters, but as a literal bracket.

Now if you want to make the change in-place, you can use `-i` like described in this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/95884/how-can-i-get-my-sed-command-to-make-permanent-changes-to-a-file). But first test without `-i`, check a part of the output to see if it looks good.

So this `sed` is expected to work for your case:

```bsh
sed -i "s/\[[^]]*\]/$key/g" file
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp is missing a '.' before '*'. If you are sure, that there is only one opening, and one closing bracket, then this should work:

`sed  "s/\[.*\]/$key/g" /tmp/file`

This prints to the stdout, if you want to edit in-place, use `sed -i`.