# Using SED to add a line after match just echos entire file

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to use `sed` in a bash file to add the following after it finds `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

```
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
```

To simplify things I am focusing just on adding the first line until I get it right, I have this so far.....

```
sed '/AddDefaultCharset UTF-8/a <IfModule mime_magic_module>' /home/testfile.ini
```

But when I try running this it just echos out the entire file, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get my sed command to make permanent changes to a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/95884/how-can-i-get-my-sed-command-to-make-permanent-changes-to-a-file)

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @Cyrus Apache configuration files might look like XML, but they aren't.

Comment: Consider `augtool` for editing config files.

Comment: Sounds like `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` doesn't exist in your file. Maybe the space is a tab instead of a blank, idk. Try just `sed -n '/AddDefaultCharset UTF-8/p'` and/or searching for smaller substrings of that (e.g. `AddDefault`, etc.) instead til you figure out where you're going wrong with your search regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-e` before your sed command(s).

```
sed -e '/AddDefaultCharset UTF-8/a <IfModule mime_magic_module>\n    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic\n</IfModule>' your_conf_file.ini
```

*NOTE:* You can use `-i.bak` to perform inplace edit and create a backup with `.bak` (or any other suffix).