# How to replace the first line using sed?

Tags: sed, awk

Hi i am trying to replace the header line from my file using the sed command as mentioned below,

```
sed "1s/.*/$new_header/" Test_file.csv
```

The above line replaces the header and prints in stdout , But How can i redirect the output to new file or replace in the files directly ?

```
sed "1s/.*/$new_header/" Test_file.csv > new_file.csv
```

The above command works fine , But i want to redirect to same file.

Comment: Two related Q/A: [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92895) [How to change a file in-place using awk? (as with "sed -i")](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/496179)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `-i` flag to `sed` which will edit in-place and also take backup:

```
sed -i.bak "1 s/.*/$new_header/" inputfile
```

Note that the `-i` option is non-standard and may work differently in different implementations of `sed`.  See [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895)