# How to change a file in-place using awk? (as with "sed -i")

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have an `awk` script, `new.awk`:

```c
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }

NR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        f[$i] = i
}

NR > 1 {
    begSecs = mktime(gensub(/[":-]/, " ", "g", $(f["DateTime"])))
    endSecs = begSecs + $(f["TotalDuration"])
    $(f["CallEndTime"]) = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", endSecs)
}

{ print }
```

I am calling this in shell

```
awk new.awk sample.csv
```

... but I can see the changes in the terminal. How to make the change in-place in the file, like when using `sed -i`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

GNU `awk` (commonly found on Linux systems), since version 4.1.0, can include an "`awk` source library" with `-i` or `--include` on the command line (see [How to safely use gawk's -i option or @include directive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/749645) along with Stéphane's comment below for security issues related to this).  One of the source libraries that is distributed with GNU `awk` is one called `inplace`:

```bash
$ cat file
hello
there
```

```bash
$ awk -i inplace '/hello/ { print "oh,", $0 }' file
$ cat file
oh, hello
```

As you can see, this makes the output of the `awk` code replace the input file.  The line saying `there` is not kept as the program does not output it.

With an `awk` script in a file, you would use it like

```bash
awk -i inplace -f script.awk datafile
```

If the `awk` variable `INPLACE_SUFFIX` is set to a string, then the library would make a backup of the original file with that as a filename suffix.

```bash
awk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak -f script.awk datafile
```

If you have several input files, each file with be individually in-place edited. But you can turn in-place editing off for a file (or a set of files) by using `inplace=0` on the command line before that file:

```bash
awk -i inplace -f script.awk file1 file2 inplace=0 file3 inplace=1 file4
```

In the above command, `file3` would not be edited in place.

---

For a more portable "in-place edit" of a single file, use

```bash
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
cp file "$tmpfile" &&
awk '...some program here...' "$tmpfile" >file
rm "$tmpfile"
```

This would copy the input file to a temporary location, then apply the `awk` code on the temporary file while redirecting to the original filename.

Doing the operations in this order (running `awk` on the temporary file, not on the original file) ensures that the file meta-data (permissions and ownership) of the original file is not modified.

Comment: I am running `ubuntu 20.04` and getting error `awk: not an option: -i`

Comment: @Satish What is important is what `awk` you're using. My answer is about GNU `awk`. What does `awk --version` say on your system? (I'm assuming it will say `awk: not an option: --version`, which will mean it's probably `mawk`, which is not GNU `awk`).

Comment: thanks for the tip. very helpful.

Comment: Should be `awk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk` or wherever that extension is on your system. Without a full path, `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`. See [How to safely use gawk's -i option or @include directive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/749645) for details.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the heads-up about this. I'll leave your comment in place and have added a parenthesis in my answer referencing the other question.

Answer (score 7):

Try this.

```
awk  new.awk sample.csv > tmp.csv && mv -f tmp.csv sample.csv
```

- redirect the output to a temp file.
- then move content of temp file to original file.

Comment: If you look at the awk inplace [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/extension/inplace.c) this is exactly what it does: creates a temporary file, redirects stdout there and at the end renames it to the input file.