# How to delete lines containing string in column n using awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

I have a tab-separated file that looks like this:

```
$ cat in_file
NC_013132.1     7260299 7261429 WP_012793281.1
NC_013132.1     7270674 7270862 NC_013132.1     7270674 7270862 ID=cds5678
NC_013132.1     7573559 7574311 WP_012793549.1
NZ_CP022095.2   2809552 2809629 NZ_CP022095.2   2809552 2809629 ID=cds2731
NZ_CP022095.2   2884046 2885668 WP_003877393.1
NZ_CP022095.2   3106358 3106435 NZ_CP022095.2   3106358 3106435 ID=cds2976
```

I want to delete lines that start with `NC` or `NZ` in column 4. I tried doing it with `awk -F '\t' '$4 != "^NC | ^NZ"' in_file` but it didn't work.

The output should look as follows:

```
$ cat out_file
NC_013132.1     7260299 7261429 WP_012793281.1
NC_013132.1     7573559 7574311 WP_012793549.1
NZ_CP022095.2   2884046 2885668 WP_003877393.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do that as below. When you use `awk` with `==` you are performing a literal string match for equality, in which you cannot do regular expression matches like `^` or `$`. You can do simply do pattern matching with `~` and turn on the negation match with `!`. For multiple patterns, use the alternation `(pat1|pat2)` style supported in ERE

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t" } $4 !~ /^(NZ|NC)/' file
```

Add a re-direction at the end of the command to write the output to a new file `> newfile`. To modify the file in-place, follow the steps in this answer [How to permanently change a file using awk? (“in-place” edits, as with “sed -i”)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496187/112235)

Answer (score 2):

You need pattern matching operator `~` (or `!~` for negation), treating the right hand operand as an (extended) regular expression on the left hand one as a string, so

```
awk -F'\t' '$4 !~ "^(NC|NZ)"' infile
```

Or shorter:

```
awk -F'\t' '$4 !~ "^N[CZ]"' infile
```

and even shorter if you don't have space within a column (since default `awk`'s FS is Tab/space):

```
awk '$4 !~ "^N[CZ]"' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below method

command

```
awk '$4 !~ /^NC|^NZ/{print $0}' filename
```

output

```
awk '$4 !~ /^NC|^NZ/{print $0}' o.txt
NC_013132.1     7260299 7261429 WP_012793281.1
NC_013132.1     7573559 7574311 WP_012793549.1
NZ_CP022095.2   2884046 2885668 WP_003877393.1
```