# How to replace an empty line with the line below it?

Tags: linux, text-processing

I've parsed a file but there's some issue and a quick way around is to replace empty line with line below it so how do I do that

like the folowing file

```
apple

banana
big
sig

cake
```

should convert to

```
apple
banana
banana
big
sig
cake
cake
```

Comment: Would removing blank lines not work?

Comment: No, actually there are two files which need to be pasted side by side.. 
and one of the file is facing this issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in `awk` with its `getline()` function. The command works by selecting the empty lines in the text file `!NF` i.e. which means those lines that are empty (number of fields within the line is 0). Using the `getline()` function we get the *next* immediate line from the empty line and store in the variable `nxt`.

```
awk '!NF && ((getline nxt) >0){ $0 = nxt ORS nxt }1' file
```

Then the part within `{..}` constructs a line combining the variable, an embedded new-line ( string concatenation with `ORS` ) and the variable back again. The 2nd append is needed, because `getline()` call by default advances the line pointer by one level. See [How to permanently change a file using awk? (“in-place” edits, as with “sed -i”)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/496179/112235) to change the file dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

With `sed`:

```
sed -ne '/./!{n;p;}' -e p your-file
```

`/./! action` runs the action (here retrieve the `n`ext line and `p`rint it) for the lines that do *not* (`!`) contain any single character (`.` is the regex operator that matches any single character).

Some `sed` implementations also have a `-i` or `-i ''` option to edit the file in-place.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^$/ { ++r; next } { print; for (i=0; i<r; ++i) print; r=0 }' file
apple
banana
banana
big
sig
cake
cake
```

or

```
awk '/^$/ { ++r; next } { print; while (r > 0) { print; --r } }' file
```

which gives the same output.

This prints each line 1 time, plus the number of times corresponding to the number of blank lines above it.  The blank lines are counted in the variable `r`.

Blank lines are detected with the regular expression `^$`, but you could also use `length == 0` or `NF == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with below sed command combination and it worked fine

```
for i in `sed -n '/^$/{n;p}' filename`; do sed -i "0,/^$/s/^$/$i/g" filename; done
```

output

```
apple
banana
banana
big
sig
cake
cake
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do this as follows:

```
$ sed -e ' /^$/{$!N' -e '}' -e 's/\n//p' inp
```

Comment: You appear to be using two different accounts (which is why your edit got put into a review queue). I'd recommend you [merge them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).