# Copy digits from end of string to another

Tags: awk, sed

How could I copy digits from one end of a string to another end of a string? So example,

Input -

```
Example123:Hello
Exp12:Hey1
Exp:heylo
```

expected output -

```
Example123:Hello123
Exp12:Hey112
Exp:heylo
```

I'm open to using sed or awk, seperator must be accounted for, so row1 is the row to extract digits from and row 2 is the row to place digits

Comment: From your expected output, it seems you want to _copy_, not _swap_ those digits from the end of the first field to the end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there's one and only one occurrence of `:` in each line of the input, you could do something like:

```
sed 's/\([[:digit:]]*\):.*/&\1/' < input
```

If there can be more than one `:` (and you want to append the digits to the end of the line, not the second field), that becomes more complicated, like:

```
sed 's/^\([^:]*[^:[:digit:]]\)\{0,1\}\([[:digit:]]*\):.*/&\2/' < input
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk here

```
awk -F':' '{ j=$1; gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",j); print $0 j }'
```

Explanation

`-F':'`: tells awk to use colon as the field separator

`j=$1; gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",j)` : assigns the first column to to a temporary variable `j`, and then removes anything that is not a digit from `j`

`print $0 j` : finally prints the original string appended with `j` that carries our number

Comment: Or `sub(/.*[^0-9]/, "", j)` in case `$1` may also contain digits other than at the end.

Answer (score 1):

With the `match()` function of GNU awk to store the matching group in an array, you could do

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: 'match($1, /([0-9]+)$/ , arr) { $2 = $2 arr[1] } 1' file
```

On any POSIX compliant `awk` you could do

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: 'match($1, /[[:digit:]]+$/) { $2 = $2 substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }; 1' file
```

See [How to permanently change a file using awk? ("in-place" edits, as with "sed -i")](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496187/112235) to make the file change persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with below script  and worked fine

```
Count_line=`awk '{print NR}' filename| sort -nr| sed -n '1p'`

for ((i=1;i<=$count_line;i++)); do awk -v i="$i" -F ":" 'NR==i{print $1}' filename| grep -o "[0-9]$">/dev/null; if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then h=`awk -v i="$i" -F ":" 'NR==i{print $1}' filename|grep -o "[0-9]*$"`; awk -v i="$i" -v h="$h" 'NR==i{print $0h}' filename; else awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{print $0}' filename; fi; done
```

output

```
Example123:Hello123
Exp12:Hey112
Exp:heylo
```

Answer (score 0):

As short as possible in bash... I think...

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\+:\).*/&\1/' < input
```

(With a bit a help from @Stèphane's earlier answer.)