# How to add columns to a file (preferably using sed -i) when there is only one column?

Tags: text-processing, sed

Say I have a column of data like this:

```
sample123
sample456
samplexyz
```

I can easily add two new columns using:

```
sed -i "s/$/\t1.1\tC/" <file.txt>
```

Now it's:

```
sample123   1.1 C
sample456   1.1 C
samplexyz   1.1 C
```

Now say I append some new data at the bottom:

```
sample123   1.1 C
sample456   1.1 C
samplexyz   1.1 C
sampleNew1
sampleNew2
sampleNew3
```

If I try to append the new columns for this data, it appends to all rows, so now when I run:

```
sed -i "s/$/\t1.2\tA/" <file.txt>
```

It looks like:

```
sample123   1.1 C   1.2 A
sample456   1.1 C   1.2 A
samplexyz   1.1 C   1.2 A
sampleNew1  1.2 A
sampleNew2  1.2 A
sampleNew3  1.2 A
```

How do I add the columns where there are no other columns except the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test first whether the current line has tab on it or not, and only do the substitution if it hasn't:

```
sed -i '/\t/!s/$/\t1.2\tA/' file
```

Here, we address all lines that does not contain a tab character using `/\t/!` and apply the substitution to those lines.

The above assumes GNU `sed` to be able to recognise `\t` as a tab character. Other `sed` implementations may need to use a literal tab character in place of `\t`.  Other `sed` implementations may also handle the `-i` option differently from GNU `sed` (see "[How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895/how-can-i-achieve-portability-with-sed-i-in-place-editing)").

---

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F "\t" 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } NF == 1 { $2 = "1.2"; $3 = "A" }; 1' file
```

This would test the number of tab-delimited fields, and if there is only a single field it would add a new second and third field before printing the line.

This would not change the file in-place.  For that, use GNU `awk` like so:

```
awk -i inplace -F "\t" 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } NF == 1 { $2 = "1.2"; $3 = "A" }; 1' file
```

For more information about `awk` and in-place edits, see "[How to permanently change a file using awk? ("in-place" edits, as with "sed -i")](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496179/how-to-permanently-change-a-file-using-awk-in-place-edits-as-with-sed-i)".

Comment: The sed command worked, thanks. Except it was `sed -i '/\t/!s/$/\t1.2\tA/'` with the `\t` at the end rather than the space. Thanks

Comment: @Luther_Blissett Ah, good, and thanks for the correction, I'll fix the answer!