# how do I remove everything in the column after the 2nd colon

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with about 7 million lines which looks like this:

```
head gokind_SNPs.txt
1:753541:G:A
1:769223:C:G
1:771967:G:A
1:778745:A:G
1:779322:A:G
...
```

How do I remove everything after the 2nd colon so that it looks like this:

```
1:753541
1:769223
1:771967
1:778745
1:779322
...
```

I tried doing this but it didn't work, the file didn't change:

```
sed 's/:[A-Z].* / /g' gokind_SNPsF.txt > gokind_SNPsf.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using awk , if you want to delete whatever character it may be..

```
awk -F":" '{ print $1":"$2 }' gokind_SNPs.txt > gokind_SNPs_OUTPUT.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command did not do anything because the regular expression you're using is trying to match a space that is not there in the data.

Instead, use

```
sed 's/:[A-Z].*//' gokind_SNPsF.txt >new-gokind_SNPsf.txt
```

This deletes all text on every line from the first `:` that is immediately followed by an upper case letter.  I've also chosen to replace with nothing, rather than with a space, and I've deleted the `g` flag which isn't necessary.

I'm assuming that you didn't *actually* run the command that you showed though, as that would have truncated (emptied) your data file before even starting `sed` (due to redirecting into the same file that you're reading from).

If you want to do in-place editing with `sed` use `sed -i`, but also read "[How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895)".

A slightly quicker alternative to your `sed` command is

```
cut -d: -f -2 gokind_SNPsF.txt >new-gokind_SNPsf.txt
```

which simply extracts the first two `:`-delimited fields from each line. Instead of `-f -2` you could use either `-f 1,2` or `-f 1-2` to specify that you want to get the first two columns.

Using `awk`, you would do

```
awk -F : 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { print $1, $2 }' gokind_SNPsF.txt >new-gokind_SNPsf.txt
```

to print only the two first fields from each line to a new file.

With GNU `awk`, you could do in-place editing with

```
awk -i inplace -F : 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { print $1, $2 }' gokind_SNPsF.txt
```

See "[How to change a file in-place using awk? (as with "sed -i")](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496179/how-to-permanently-change-a-file-using-awk-in-place-edits-as-with-sed-i)" for more about that.

Comment: OP's command clobbers input only on a case-insensitive filesystem, typically Windows/WSL or MacOS. But it is clearer and safer to use a more obvious difference like 'NEW' or 'OUTPUT' or 'TEMP'. `sponge` is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

The `cut` command is designed for exactly this:

```
cut -d: -f-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Never try to write to the same file you're trying to read:

```
sed 's/:[A-Z].* / /' gokind_SNPsF.txt > tmp && mv tmp gokind_SNPsf.txt
```

or use `sed -i` if your version of sed supports it.