# Delete duplicate lines in file without creating new file in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, text-processing, numeric-data

I can't seem to find a command that lets me delete duplicates in my file without creating a new file and also preserving the order of the contents in my file.

Would there be another command besides `uniq` and `awk`?

If not, I know that `sed` contains an in place option. I just don't know how to use it with deleting duplicates.

with duplicates
sample.txt

```
1
2
1
3
4
1
```

deleted duplicates
sample.txt

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: If you're using a *recent* version of Ubuntu, you likely have GNU awk (`gawk`) by default - which does have a `-i inplace` option

Comment: Something to note is that any program performing this action will use a temporary file under the hood and then replace the target file once it's done. Using `uniq`, redirecting to a temp file, then moving that file to replace the target isn't necessarily a bad thing. Invoking `awk` or `sed` might make things more complicated when you come back to the command later.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `awk` specifically, and its recently gained ability to do in-place edits,

```
$ cat file
1
2
1
3
4
1
```

```
$ awk -i inplace '!seen[$0]++' file
```

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
```

Note that as with most tools that do "in-place edits" (e.g. `sed -i`), this uses a temporary file to perform the editing.  You do however not have to manually move files about.

See also:

- [How to change a file in-place using awk? (as with "sed -i")](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496179/how-to-change-a-file-in-place-using-awk-as-with-sed-i)
- [How does awk '!a[$0]++' work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159695/how-does-awk-a0-work)

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of corrupting the file if the command is aborted:

```
{ awk '!seen[$0]++'; 
 python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.truncate(sys.stdout.tell())'; } <sample.txt 1<>sample.txt
```

We create a grouping of commands within the curly braces, redirecting standard input for the group to `sample.text` while also opening `sample.txt` in read+write mode sans truncation via the `1<>sample.txt` .

`awk '!seen[$0]++'` is the [awk idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1444448/753731) for removing duplicates whilst preserving order

When the `awk` command ends, the file descriptor corresponding to the standard output is positioned at some intermediate location within `sample.txt` and `sample.txt` needs to be truncated down to this location.
There are two ways I can think of to accomplish this

1. `python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.truncate(sys.stdout.tell())'` is an option if `python` is installed
2. On a GNU Linux system `truncate -s "$(awk '/^pos:/{print $2}' /proc/$$/fdinfo/1)" sample.txt`

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to use `sort` with `-o`

```
sort -u sample.txt -o sample.txt
```

`-u` is for unique

`-o` is for output filename

Comment: `sort -u` is not guaranteed to preserve original order which is an OP requirement