# How to correctly find a line number with awk and delete it with sed in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to delete a specific line of a file in bash.

What I am currently doing is to get the line number and pass it so `sed` to delete this line:

```
awk '/qr/{ print NR; exit }' test | sed -i "${1}d" test
```

The `awk` part works well, but in this state, the `sed` part deletes all the content of the file (named test).

However, when I do it without the variable :

```
sed -i '1d' test
```

It works fine.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: sed does not read $1 from a pipeline (if it gets a filename arg, it won't read stdin at all). The $1 is expanded by the shell even before either of the processes in the pipeline are executed. So the sed expression is just "d", and it deleted every line.

Comment: Ok, good to know. But do I have to store the return of the awk in a variable in order to use it with sed ? @Paul_Pedant

Comment: What speaks against doing the job completely in `awk`, as in `awk '/qr/{if (!i++) next}1' test` (*assuming you only want to remove the first occurence*)? If you need "inplace" function, GNU `awk` > 4.1.0 supports the `-i inplace` command-line option for that.

Comment: For non-huge files, I store the whole file in an array X[NR], mark lines for deletion in D[NR], and write the lot back to FILENAME in the END block. That means you can do stuff like mark multiple lines, paragraphs containing any number of specific words, etc. So a generic solution, but it's not for everybody.

Comment: I didn't know about "inplace". My way does not use tmp files, and I can abort it cleanly if no change is needed, or I find a data error. I need to check what inplace does if I exit (1) somewhere.

Comment: @AdminBee What prevents me is the knowladge about it ^^. Also, I need inplace and but have gnu awk 4.0.2. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Ok, that's bad luck ... ;)

Comment: @FlorianCastelain can't you install a more current gawk version (we're currently on version 5.1.0), you're missing some very useful functionality (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History) and a few bug fixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${1}` is replaced by the first argument in the current context; it doesn’t read anything from `awk`’s output in your example.

If you want to keep both `awk` and `sed`, one way to go about this is to store the output of `awk` in a variable:

```
line=$(awk '/qr/{ print NR; exit }' test); sed -i "${line}d" test
```

but that won’t work well if the file doesn’t have any line containing “qr”.

A better approach might be to use `sed` only:

```
sed -i "/qr/d" test
```

but that will delete all matching lines, not just the first one.

The AWK (or rather, `gawk`, the GNU implementation, [starting with version 4.1.0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496187/86440)) equivalent of the above is

```
gawk -i inplace '!/qr/' test
```

or, replacing only the first instance,

```
gawk -i inplace '/qr/ && !i { i++; next; } 1' test
```

Comment: That first command would completely wipe out your input file if it didn't contain `qr`, you'd need to make it `line=$(awk '/qr/{ print NR; f=1; exit } END{exit !f}' test) && sed -i "${line}d" test` if you were really going to do something like that.

Comment: Right, that’s why there’s a “but” ;-). Thanks for the working version!

Comment: Yeah at first I didn't see the `but` and then once I did I thought `won’t work well` was kinda understating the impact so decided to comment :-). You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Given this input file:

```
$ cat file
foo
qr
bar
```

If you were really going to use that approach then it'd be (without `-i` so you can see the effect of the sed):

```
$ awk '/qr/{print NR; exit}' file | xargs -n 1 -I {} sed '{}d' file
foo
bar
```

but of course that's a pointless pipe to xargs+sed and what you should do instead is just:

```
awk '!f && /qr/{f=1; next} 1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

or with a recent version of gawk that supports it:

```
awk -i inplace '!f && /qr/{f=1; next} 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to remove the first occurence of the pattern, you can use `awk` entirely:

```
awk '/qr/{if (!i++) next}1' test
```

This will print all lines (`1`) except for the first line matching `/qr/` (where `i` is still zero, and hence the `next` command will be issued before the "print" action can become effective).

If you need the "inplace" editing function of `sed -i`, *and* you have GNU `awk` > 4.1.0, you can make use of the "inplace" extension:

```
awk -i inplace '/qr/{if (!i++) next}1' test
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just delete the first matching line then

```
sed  "0,/qr/{/qr/d;}" file
```

Just drop `-i`nline in after testing

This only processes the addresses from the first line to the first match with `qr`

```
0,/qr/
```

and the deletes any line in that address range that contains `qr`

```
{/qr/d;}
```