# Remove the last rows with no data but just commas from a CSV file through shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed

I am generating a CSV file which ideally should have 1-row or 2-row data but it is coming like

```
11,ABC,3,4,5,6
,,,,,
```

I have tried sed and awk commands to remove that empty row but it didn't work out

```
sed -i 's/,,//g' fileName.csv
```

(as this isn't a dynamic solution when we have odd number of commas)

```
awk -F, 'length>NF+1' fileName.csv > fileName.csv
```

(when I try to put that into the file it's removing all the rows from the file. Maybe my inexperience with sed and awk commands is the issue).

Comment: How are you generating the CSV data? It seems that it should be possible to produce the data correctly from the start instead of relying on a post-processing step to correct it after the fact.

Comment: It is coming through a tool with which I can't do much. Editing the data through the shell script for sending it ahead would be an easier solution

Comment: There are 4 files which needs to be treated. And each of them have different number of fields

Comment: Having suffered this issue myself, you might need to beware of additional junk such as completely blank lines, training whitespace, and carriage returns. The problem seems to arise from slapdash selection of data during Excel exports.

Comment: Can your data also have lines of all commas BEFORE the last line that contains non-commas and, if so, do you want those lines removed too or only the lines after the last line that contains non-commas? See the sample input/output in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670491/133219) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the data through

```bsh
grep '[^,]'
```

would extract lines that contain any character that is not a comma.  It would effectively remove lines that *only* includes commas.

For example:

```bsh
grep '[^,]' filename.csv >newname.csv
```

Note that you can't redirect to the same name you are reading from as the shell would truncate (empty) the file to which you are redirecting before executing `grep`.

You could also do this as an in-place edit with `sed` if your `sed` implementation supports this syntax:

```bsh
sed -n -i '/[^,]/p' filename.csv
```

or

```bsh
sed -i '/[^,]/!d' filename.csv
```

[In-place editing using GNU `awk`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496179/how-to-change-a-file-in-place-using-awk-as-with-sed-i):

```bsh
awk -i inplace '/[^,]/' filename.csv
```

Comment: sed -n -i '/[^,]/p' filename.csv 

This worked for me
Was not able to do this in-place edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do what you asked for, `Remove the last rows with no data but just commas from a CSV file through shell script`, would be:

```
tac file | awk '/[^,]/{f=1} f' | tac
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
a,b,c
d,e,f
,,,
g,h,i
,,,
,,,
```

```
$ tac file | awk '/[^,]/{f=1} f' | tac
a,b,c
d,e,f
,,,
g,h,i
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer provided by Kusalananda

```
sed -n -i '/[^,]/p' filename.csv
```

worked totally fine for me.

Also, I found a workaround to that using awk and file

`awk -F ',' '$2>" " {print $0}' file.csv > temp.csv && mv temp.csv file.csv`

This is not the ideal solution but works too

Comment: `-i` does not make sense by itself with GNU `awk`. Your `awk` code could be shortened to just `$2 > " "` (it would print the current line by default), but this looks odd. Why would you arbitrarily test the 2nd field and no other field?

Comment: sorry, not the -i

Comment: Don't post a new answer that contains someone else's answer (the sed script) and that awk script doesn't make any sense.