# Remove https characters in a text file

Tags: linux

I need to remove all http and https from txt file.

Like this:

```
http://ac.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
http://go.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
http://lp.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
https://ac.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
http://secreto.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
https://go.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
https://lp.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
https://secreto.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
```

To

```
ac.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
go.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
lp.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
ac.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
secreto.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
go.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
lp.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
secreto.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
```

I tryed using sed but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer `awk` to `sed`, so here's what I'd do:

`awk` allows you to define custom *field separators*, which makes your problem fairly straightforward:

Assuming the file containing the full URLs is `tstfile.txt`, declare the *field separator* (`-F`) as `//`, and then print the second field (`$2`):

```
$ awk -F'//' '{print $2}' tstfile.txt
ac.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
go.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
lp.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
ac.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
secreto.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
go.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
lp.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
secreto.tecnicasdeinvasao.com
```

If you want the results in a file, you can use a redirection `>somefile.txt`.

And if your distro uses the GNU version of `awk`, a.k.a. `gawk`, you have the option of updating your input file ***in-place***:

```
$ awk -i inplace -F'//' '{print $2}' tstfile.txt
$
```

Now, the contents of `tstfile.txt` will be exactly as shown above, which may save you a step or two - depending on your end objective. Other options, including saving the original file under a different file name are covered in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496187/286615).

Comment: that worked! what mean {print $2}? why this worked?

Comment: @Chead: Generally speaking, `awk` treats each *line* as a `record`, and each `record` has one or more `fields`. A `field separator` tells `awk` what the field boundaries are. In this case, because we declared `//` as the `field separator`, the characters to the left of the `field separator` is the first field, the chars to the right are the second field. As `awk` reads the line/record, each `field` is stored in `$1` (first record), `$2` (2nd record), etc. This worked because we declared `//` as the `field separator`, and printed the second field: `$2`. Lots of good tutorials on `awk` online.

Answer (score 2):

###### Because you asked with sed

With **sed** easier to read:

```bsh
sed  -E 's/http.+[/]//'
```

With **sed** easier to write:

```bsh
sed -E 's/http.+\///'
```

Both do the same. **sed** use the format of `/select/replace/`, because of this is harder to read with `\` backlash.

- `-E` is to use regular expression "newer" versions
- `s` is for find and replace a **s**tring
- `.+` has 2 meanings, the `.` dot is for any character, in this case the s and the `+` sign is for selecting  everything else after the `.`
- if a character has special meaning in regex world, you need to escape them, usually with `\` backlash. In this case, you require telling **sed** to select everything until the last `/`, so you require escaping it like this `\/` but is harder to read `\///`, the last `//` is from the format of `/select/replace/` you can also escape with brackets `[/]`, and because you want to remove what you have selected then you write nothing --> `//`

and because everything starts with **h**(is the same), so you can make it even shorter

```bsh
sed -E 's/.+\///'  
sed -E 's/.+[/]//'
```

this means --> select everything from the beginning of the TEXT until the last `/` --> `whateverGoesHere`**/**

Comment: Note that in cases where the search pattern or replacement string contain `/`, it is easiest to instruct `sed` to use a different command argument separator, e.g. `sed -E 's|http.+/||'` or `sed -E 's,http.+/,,'`

Comment: man you were so good to explain sed! now i understood! thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk '{sub(/https?:\/\//,"");print}' file.txt > outfile.txt
```

`awk` loops through the input lines performing the program on each line.  I didn't specify any regular expression to match, so the code in curly braces is executed on each line.  The `sub` function matches the regular expression between slashes and replaces it with the quoted empty string.  The question mark in the regular expression makes the "s" optional