# sed + add string on the beginning of line but ignore if already exist

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, perl

here is example how to add string on the beginning of line when match the UUID number in fstab

```
sed -e "/UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a/ s/^/###FAULTY_DISK###/"  -i /etc/fstab
```

and we can verify with

```
more /etc/fstab 

###FAULTY_DISK###UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a /data/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

but on the second running we get

```
sed -e "/UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a/ s/^/###FAULTY_DISK###/"  -i /etc/fstab


more /etc/fstab
###FAULTY_DISK######FAULTY_DISK###UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a /data/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

how to tell sed to ignore the adding of `###FAULTY_DISK###` , in case it already set in file fstab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [comment the specific line in fstab file that contained the relevant UUID number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687916/comment-the-specific-line-in-fstab-file-that-contained-the-relevant-uuid-number)  The accepted answer does what you want, and does not add the comment character (which could be a longer string if you wish) more than once upon re-running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Append only if it was starting with that UUID:

```
sed -e 's/^UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a/###FAULTY_DISK###&/' /etc/fstab
```

or, in case you wanted to ignore leading whitespace too if any:

```
sed -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a/###FAULTY_DISK###&/' /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to just skip lines with `###FAULTY_DISK###`. Consider this example file that has one line with the faulty disk comment and another without:

```
$ cat fstab 
UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a /data/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
###FAULTY_DISK###UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a /data/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

You can use the `n` command in `sed` to move to the next line. So tell `sed` to move to the next line if this one matches the faulty message:

```
$ sed  "/###FAULTY_DISK###/n; s/UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a/###FAULTY_DISK###&/" fstab 
###FAULTY_DISK###UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a /data/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
###FAULTY_DISK###UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a /data/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

As you can see, the message was only added to the line that did not have it.

Comment: You'd want to use `b` instead of `n` here (and use two `-e`xpressions). With `n` here, if both line 1 and line 2 contain `FAULTY_DISK` and line 2 contains the UUID, you'll add an extra FAULTY_DISK

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

Given

```
##FAULTY_DISK###UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a
UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a
```

Then

```bsh
$ sed '/^###FAULTY_DISK###UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a/!s/^UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a/###FAULTY_DISK###&/' /etc/fstab 
###FAULTY_DISK###UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a
###FAULTY_DISK###UUID=953b1921-ac73-4b7b-abaf-ff983b0fce8a
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by explaining what `!` does and why it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -pe 's/ ^ ("UUID=86d58af9-801b-4c25-b59d-80b52b4acc61") /\#\#\#FAULTY_DISK\#\#\#$0/;' fstab_test.txt
```

OR

```perl
raku -pe 's[ ^ ("UUID=86d58af9-801b-4c25-b59d-80b52b4acc61") ] = "\#\#\#FAULTY_DISK\#\#\#$0";'
```

The answers above are written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Once prepended with `###FAULTY_DISK###`, a line in the `fstab` file is ignored during subsequent runs of the same Raku one-liner, i.e. the modification is stable.

See below link for Sample Input and Sample Output.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689556/227738