# bash: How to add column numbers to the first row

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I had many large .txt like:

```
xx yy ... zz 
XX YY ... ZZ
```

I want to add a header row to them, each with a different number of columns:

```
1 2 ... 999
xx yy ... zz
XX YY ... ZZ
```

Since they have a different number of columns, I could not directly type "1\t2\t....", and I guess that the code should include variables like `$NF`. Do you have any idea? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",i,i==NF?ORS:OFS}1' file
```

Add `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` at the beginning of your `awk` script if you have a tab-delimited file.

[Check here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496179/how-to-change-a-file-in-place-using-awk-as-with-sed-i) how to edit your file inplace.