# Using "sed" to insert text at the end of a field in TSV file

Tags: text-processing, sed, bioinformatics

I want to insert characters in TSV files using the `sed` command with wildcard expressions:

I have a file like this:

```
Marker  Pvalue  Trait   Chr Pos
S3_16887238 6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_S    3   16887238
S3_16887238 6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_Pa   3   16887238
S3_16887238 6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_Cl   3   16887238
```

And I want to add `_All` at the end of all the texts in the third column like this:

```
Marker  Pvalue  Trait   Chr Pos
S3_16887238 6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_S_All    3   16887238
S3_16887238 6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_Pa_All   3   16887238
S3_16887238 6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_Cl_All   3   16887238
```

I am using this command and it is not working:

```
sed -i 's/Total_Soil_\(.*\)/&_\1_All/g' top1.txt
```

This is just an example file, there could be anything instead of `S`, `Pa`, and `Cl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid working on tabular data with `sed` as it's difficult to correctly address the exact positions in the data that you want to modify.  The `sed` utility is more suitable for processing unstructured data like text.

---

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`; a tool specifically made for working with structured data) to append the string `_All` to the end of the data in the `Trait` field of each TSV record:

```bash
$ mlr --tsv put '$Trait .= "_All"' file
Marker  Pvalue  Trait   Chr     Pos
S3_16887238     6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_S_All        3       16887238
S3_16887238     6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_Pa_All       3       16887238
S3_16887238     6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_Cl_All       3       16887238
```

Use `mlr` with its `-I` option to do the change in-place.

Would you need to ensure that you are modifying the field only if it starts with the string `Total_Soil`, then use

```bash
mlr --tsv put '$Trait =~ "^Total_Soil" { $Trait .= "_All" }' file
```

---

With `awk`, appending the string `_All` to the end of the data in the 3rd tab-delimited field of each record:

```bash
$ awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } NR > 1 { $3 = $3 "_All" }; 1' file
Marker  Pvalue  Trait       Chr     Pos
S3_16887238     6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_S_All        3       16887238
S3_16887238     6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_Pa_All       3       16887238
S3_16887238     6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_Cl_All       3       16887238
```

The trailing `1` at the end of the `awk` code causes the modified record to be unconditionally outputted. It is, in a way, a short-hand way of writing `{ print }`. Note that we explicitly need to avoid modifying the header. We do this by testing using `NR > 1` and modifying the field only if the test evaluates to *true* (`NR` is the ordinal number of the current record).

Redirect the output to a new file and then rename the new file to the original name. Or, if you are using GNU `awk`, use `-i inplace` as described [in another question+answer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496179/how-to-change-a-file-in-place-using-awk-as-with-sed-i)

Again, if you need to ensure that you only modify the 3rd field if it starts with the string `Total_Soil`, then use

```bash
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } NR > 1 && $3 ~ /^Total_Soil/ { $3 = $3 "_All" }; 1' file
```

---

Using Perl in pretty much the same way as `awk`:

```bash
$ perl -F'\t' -e 'BEGIN { $" = "\t" } if ($. > 1) { $F[2] .= "_All" } print "@F"' file
Marker  Pvalue  Trait   Chr     Pos
S3_16887238     6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_S_All        3       16887238
S3_16887238     6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_Pa_All       3       16887238
S3_16887238     6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_Cl_All       3       16887238
```

Ensuring we only modify `Total_Soil` data:

```bash
perl -F'\t' -e 'BEGIN { $" = "\t" } if ($. > 1 && $F[2] =~ /^Total_Soil/) { $F[2] .= "_All" } print "@F"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN put get; my @a = .split("\t"); @a.[2] = @a.[2] ~ "_All"; put @a.join("\t");' file
```

Raku is a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. An advantage of Raku is high-level support for Unicode built-in, no external libraries (or special flags) required.

Above is a fairly direct translation of @Kusalananda's excellent Perl(5) answer. Raku's `-ne` non-autoprinting "linewise" commandline flags are used. To print the headerline verbatim, use a `BEGIN` phaser that `put get` puts (print-using-terminator) the first line it `get`s.

The body of the linewise commands works like so: declare an array with `my @a` and assign to it the input line `$_` that has been `.split("\t")` on tabs [ `.split("\t")` is short for `$_.split("\t")` ].

Take `@a.[2]` the third element (i.e. column) and over-write it with the same element, `@a.[2] ~ "_All"` tilde-concatenated with a trailing `_All` string.

Then take all `@a` elements, `join`ed back together on tabs, and out`put`.

Sample Input:

```
Marker  Pvalue  Trait   Chr Pos
S3_16887238 6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_S    3   16887238
S3_16887238 6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_Pa   3   16887238
S3_16887238 6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_Cl   3   16887238
```

Sample Output:

```
Marker  Pvalue  Trait   Chr Pos
S3_16887238 6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_S_All    3   16887238
S3_16887238 6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_Pa_All   3   16887238
S3_16887238 6.172847e-09    Total_Soil_Cl_All   3   16887238
```

https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

With sed you can do:

```
sed 's/Total_Soil_[^[:blank:]]*/&_All/' top1.txt
```

To do it inline, add an `-i` after sed

*Edit*: Substituted `[^ ]` with `[^[:blank:]]` to match everything but *Spaces* and *Tabs*.

Comment: Note that the delimiter is a tab, not a space.

Comment: I changed my answer, now the delimiter can be spaces or tabs.