# Using literal empty curly braces {} inside sed command from find -exec

Tags: sed, find

I'm wondering if it is possible to include empty curly braces `{}` inside a `sed` replacement called from a `find -exec`.

An example:

```
find "$dir" -type f -name "*" -exec sed -i s/hello{}a/hello{}b/g '{}' +
```

This brings up the error message of duplicate `{}`:

`find: Only one instance of {} is supported with -exec ... +`

Is there a way to keep `{}` in the `sed` command and to be seen as literals, not as replacements for the files that `find` finds?

Comment: As an aside, you don't need single quotes around `{}`, and `-name "*"` is superfluous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, you can work around `find`'s exec grammar by capturing a brace expression and using a back reference in the replacement text:

```
$ cat f1 f2
f1: hello{}a
f2: hello{}a
$ find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/hello\([{][}]\)a/hello\1b/g' '{}' +
$ cat f1 f2
f1: hello{}b
f2: hello{}b
```

Or, more simply (as noted in the comments):

```
find "$dir" -type f -exec sed -i 's/\(hello[{]}\)a/\1b/g' {} +
```

---

Note that the `-i` option for Sed is not portable and will not work everywhere.  The given command will work on GNU Sed only.

For details, see:

- [How to achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92895/135943)

Comment: If you're already using a backreference, there's no reason not to include `hello` in it.  And putting one curly brace in brackets should be enough; you don't need to do both.

Comment: (And you don't need single quotes around `{}`.)

Comment: `find "$dir" -type f -exec sed -i 's/\(hello[{]}\)a/\1b/g' {} +`

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you're using `+` which means that `-exec` can put *multiple* arguments in place of `{}`.  There's no way this is what you intended when combined with your `sed` command, and it's possible (though very implementation-dependent) that you can get the result you want by simply removing the `+`.

However the general way to do this is by using `sh -c`:

```
find "$dir" -type f -exec sh -c 'sed -i "s/hello$1a/hello$1b/g" "$1"' sh {} \;
```

Comment: I should have been more clear in my original question. I do want multiple arguments. I want the `{}` in the `sed` command to be seen as literal braces, not as replacements for the files the `find` command finds.

Comment: @mrbnny, fair enough.  In that case [Barefoot IO's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265902/135943) is what you need (though it can be simplified—see my comments on that answer).