# using Sed to find and replace a string inside a file

Tags: sed, osx

I have been trying to replace '{{date}}' with a current date stamp in OSX command line. I have been using the following:

```
sed -i -e 's/{{date}}/`date`/g' mhp.xml
```

Does anyone know why it ends up putting

```
`date`
```

instead of the actual date?

When I try

```
date=`date`
echo $date
```

it works... and shows the current date. Any ideas?

Comment: The reason WHY your version didn't work is because you used single-quotes around the `sed` script rather than double-quotes.  text inside single-quotes is treated as a fixed string literal.  Text inside double-quotes is interpolated by the shell, with variable expansions, command substitution (like `$(date)`), etc applied.  Both forms are useful, sometimes you want string literals, sometimes you want interpolation, sometimes you want both (which requires careful use of quoting and escaping).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i "s/{{date}}/$(date)/g" mhp.xml
```

With BSD sed:

```
sed -i '' "s/{{date}}/$(date)/g" mhp.xml
```

Comment: Ok so the BSD one worked on mac osx but do those single quotes signify?

Comment: the `-i` option on BSD `sed` requires an argument.  `''` gives it an empty string as its argument.   GNU `sed` supports an optional argument for `-i` so doesn't require the `''` empty string.

Comment: @MaximusPeters: BSD sed requires those to empty suffix edit in-place work, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92895/38906