# Change the position of string in line

Tags: text-processing

I would like to move the first string between `>` and the first `_` to the second position after the first `_`

This is to transform this:

```
>10E13JB10_Vacares_8__a1
blablabla
>10E13JB10_Vacares_8__a2
blablabla
>10E2JB10_Mulhacen_13__a1
blablabla
```

Into this:

```
>Vacares_10E13JB10_8__a1
blablabla
>Vacares_10E13JB10_8__a2
blablabla
>Mulhacen_10E2JB10_13__a1
blablabla
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/^>\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)/>\2_\1/' -i file
```

Find the first two strings terminated by `_`, and reverse their order in the substitution. Since it only matches the first two strings, it does not modify or discard the rest of the line.

- `s/aaa/bbb/` - perform a substitution, replacing all occurrences of `aaa` with `bbb`
- `^` - begin of line
- `\(...\)` - *capture groups*, which save the matched strings as `\1` and `\2`
- `[^_]*` - a *character class* matching all characters except `_`

Comment: You should explain what you're doing here at least a little bit.

Comment: I agree with Centimane. Someone new to regexes will freak when they see this... I added a (prose) description, but it's under peer review.

Comment: Note that `-i` (for in place editing) is a GNU extension, not standard Sed.  But this is still a good answer.  Also see [How to achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92895/135943)