# insert character in the beginning of specified line in file

Tags: text-processing

I need to insert character (#) in the beginning of specified line in a text file.

Input example:

```
Hellow1
Hellow2
Hellow3
```

Desired output

```
Hellow1
#Hellow2
Hellow3
```

Comment: How we're supposed to find the "specified line" ? Is it by line number ? Is it by specific text ? Is it by specific search pattern ? Please clarify  your question

Answer (score 20):

To insert a `#` on the line that starts with the word `Hellow2`, you may use `sed` like this:

```
sed '/^Hellow2/ s/./#&/' input.txt >output.txt
```

To insert a `#` in the beginning of the second line of a text, you may use `sed` like this:

```
sed '2 s/./#&/' input.txt >output.txt
```

The `&` will be replaced by whatever was matched by the pattern.

I'm avoiding using `sed -i` (in-place editing), because I don't know what `sed` you are using and most implementations of `sed` use incompatible ways of handling that flag (see [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895)).

Instead, do the substitution like above and then

```
mv output.txt input.txt
```

if you want to replace the original data with the result.  This also gives you a chance to make sure it came out correctly.

Equivalent thing with `awk`:

```
awk '/^Hellow2/ { $0 = "#" $0 }; 1' input.txt >output.txt

awk 'NR == 2 { $0 = "#" $0 }; 1' input.txt >output.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Your question is unclear. Assuming you're looking to comment out the specific text:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^\(Hellow2\)$/#\1/'
```

This will do an in-place replacement of any lines that exactly match the string "Hellow2", and replace them with a # followed by the line that was matched.

Comment: It works and save it to the file - Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The general pattern to apply an `s` command to specific lines is `[2addr]s...`  Where `2addr` represents 0, 1 or 2 addresses.  In other words, if you want to insert a # before lines that match a pattern:

```
sed -e '/pattern/s/^/#/'
```

If you want to do the replacement on line `$n`:

```
sed -e "${n}s/^/#/"  # (This requires that $n be a well formatted number)
```

If you want to match the range of lines $n to $m:

```
sed -e "${n},${m}s/^/#/"  # $n and $m must be well formed numbers.  eg '2'
```

If you want to match all lines between a line that matches `pattern1` and a line that matches `pattern2:

```
sed -e '/pattern1/,/pattern2/s/^/#/'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert before lines **2 to 4** you can specify range.

```
sed -i -e '2,4s/^/# /' test.txt
```

If you want specific lines, **not range**, it should be in different expressions. (for example lines 2 and 4 but not 3.)

```
sed -i -e '2s/^/# /' -e '4s/^/# /' test.txt
```

##### For the OP, combining the two leading answers here:

credit:
@kusalananda, @brian-c

`sed -i -e 's/^Hellow2/# &/' my-file.txt`

- This will search for `Hellow2` at the beginning of the line.
- When the word matches, the entire match will be stored at ref 0 - which is accessed with `&` character.
- We then replace that with:

  - hash sign
  - followed by a space
  - and then the entire match

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `awk`:

```
awk '{if ($0 == "Hellow2") print "#"$0; else print $0}' yourfile > outputfile
```

Comment: This can be shortened with `awk '$0=="Hellow2"{print "#"$0;next};1' input.txt`. The pattern before each code block `{}` can be treated as `if` statement already. `1` Just tells awk to print the line, that's all

Comment: @Serg Thanks for your info, you are totally right, but, i wanted it to be clear

Comment: but it do not save it to the file.. how can I save it?

Comment: @user210015 I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```perl
raku -pe 's/^/#/ if $++ == 1;'  yourfile > outputfile
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne 'state $i; S/^/{"#" if $i++ == 1}/.put;'  yourfile > outputfile
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne 'if $++ == 1 {S/^/#/.put;} else {$_.put};'  yourfile > outputfile
```

Above are solutions coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of languages. Indexing in Raku starts from zero, so `$++ == 1` or `$i++ == 1` denotes the second line.

The first example uses the autoprinting `-pe` command line flags in conjunction with the familar "small-s" `s///` operator. The second and third example use the non-autoprinting `-ne`command line flags in conjunction with the "large-S" `S///` operator. The "large-S" operator has the property that it... *"uses the same semantics as the `s///` operator, except it leaves the original string intact and returns the resultant string... ."*

Sample Input:

```
Hellow1
Hellow2
Hellow3
```

Sample Output:

```
Hellow1
#Hellow2
Hellow3
```

https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/wiki/Running-rakudo-from-the-command-line
https://docs.raku.org/syntax/s$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS
https://docs.raku.org/syntax/S$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

## Simple is Good

I am writing because I feel other answers are complicating things.

To replace the 2nd line:

```bsh
printf 'Hellow1\nHellow2\nHellow3\n' | sed '2s/^/#&/'
```

```
Hellow1
#Hellow2
Hellow3
```

To replace `Hellow2`:

```bsh
printf 'Hellow1\nHellow2\nHellow3\n' | sed 's/^Hellow2$/#&/'
```

```
Hellow1
#Hellow2
Hellow3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require all even lines to be suffixed with a `#`
then:

```bash
sed '2~2 s/./#&/' your file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -i 's/string/#&' file
```

string should be entered from starting

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please indicate in what way your answer is different from that of [@Brian C](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336770/377345) or that of [@Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336774/377345).

Comment: @AdminBee One difference is that this solution has a syntax error in it, so....