# BSD sed vs. GNU sed, and -i

Tags: sed, gnu, bsd

Unix iMac shell terminal

```
sed -i 's/original/new/g' maths.tx
```

Message returned:   sed: -i may not be used with stdin

Comment: Very related, possible duplicate: [How to achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895/how-to-achieve-portability-with-sed-i-in-place-editing)

Comment: I don't have a Mac to test with; why does it complain about working on stdin when you've provided a file to process? Was the command instead `sed -i 's/original/new/g' < maths.txt` (note the addition of the less-than sign)

Comment: I have a Linux/macOS/BSD solution to this in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65497543/117471

Answer (score 20):

Macs use the BSD version of utilities such as `sed` and `date`, which have their own idiosyncrasies.

In this specific case, the BSD build of `sed` *mandates* the extension for the backup file with `-i`, rather than it being *optional*, as in GNU `sed`.

As such:

```
sed -i .bak 's/needle/pin/g' haystack
```

The shown command will replace all instances of `needle` with `pin` in the file `haystack`, and the original file will be preserved in `haystack.bak`.

From the manual for the implementation of `sed` on a Mac:

> ```
> -i extension
>          Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.
>          It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in
>          situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.
> ```

As opposed to on a Linux host:

> ```
>   -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
>           edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
> ```

Note that "a zero-length extension" is distinct from "no extension".  You can eschew the backup entirely, then, with:

```
sed -i '' 's/needle/pin/g' haystack
```

Comment: that seem to work for my Mac sed -i ''

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  Welcome to U&L!  If this answer was helpful, please 'Accept' the answer so that people perusing questions know that it has been answered and can find a solution here.

Comment: @Kam Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Accurate answer, just what I was looking for, I want to say that many utilities on the osx are different from GNU, for example, also grep utility. Please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: I'd add, if you want something portable (GNU and BSD sed), you might want to write `sed -i.bak ...` (no space, and a dot). This leads to create a backup file. If you don't want it, as you know the filename anyway, it's easy to add a `&& rm filename.ext.bak` after the `sed`. This way works on both sed versions.

Comment: `sed -i .bak` is also portable, for the record.  The space is optional.  As, for that matter, is the `.`; it's just that if you do `sed -i bak` for a file `file`, the backup would then be called `filebak` which some might not find as readable.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify a backup file, like:

```
sed -i .bak 's/original/new/g' maths.tx
```