# I want to replace exact word using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

My aim is to add `"` double quote when ever the below word are coming in file

```
VGHIER_TSV_WB798
CBVGHIER_TSV_WB798
```

here

```
sed -i 's/"VGHIER_TSV_WB798"./VGHIER_TSV_WB798./g'
```

is used to remove the double quote if any allready prasent
and

```
sed -i 's/VGHIER_TSV_WB798./"VGHIER_TSV_WB798"./g'
```

to add the quote
but the issue I am getting when we got the `CBVGHIER_TSV_WB798` it is repalced as
`CB"VGHIER_TSV_WB798"`, which I don't want
I have separate sed statement to repalce the secodn word

```
sed -i 's/CBVGHIER_TSV_WB798./"CBVGHIER_TSV_WB798"./g'
```

could you please help me how to achive the above requiement.

Comment: So the problem is when this string appears in a longer word -- please could you show us some example content from the input file? Are these words the only thing on the line?  Also, which version of `sed` are you using?

Comment: @JigglyNaga - isn't -i a GNU thing?

Comment: @Guy It's non-standard, but often implemented (although with varying semantics). See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401905/bsd-sed-vs-gnu-sed-and-i

Answer (score 2):

If your `sed` supports EREs, you could add the `CB` as an optional part of the pattern to match. This would replace both of those:

```
sed -E 's/(CB)?VGHIER_etc/"\1VGHIER_etc"/g'  test
```

Or, if your `sed` supports `\<` and `\>` for start and end of word, use those:

```
sed 's/\<VGHIER_etc\>/"VGHIER_etc"/g'  test
```

Also, you have a trailing dot `.` in the pattern, it will match any character, and it will be replaced as part of the string. The dot in the replacement will put a literal dot back. `s/foo./"foo"./` changes `food` to `"foo".`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add a leading prefix to your search string. If the word that you are trying to replace will always be preceded by a space:

```
sed -i 's/ VGHIER_TSV_WB798\./ "VGHIER_TSV_WB798"./g'
```

More generically, you can use the regex grouping `[[:space:]]` to cover cases of leading spaces or tabs etc (see `man isspace` for complete list).

```
sed -i 's/\([[:space:]]\)VGHIER_TSV_WB798\./\1"VGHIER_TSV_WB798"./g'
```

In that case, we needed to add an additional complexity by creating a regex grouping using the escaped parentheses, and use a *back reference* `\1` to be sure not to lose the exact character when performing the replacement. There is also a regex class `[[:punct:]]` for punctuation characters, in case the word is preceded sometimes by one of them. See `man isspace` for a complete detailed list of what each regex character class covers.

Here's a more complex example solution to cover the case of possible punctuation prefixes:

```
sed -i 's/\([[:space:]]\|[[:punct:]]\)VGHIER_TSV_WB798\./\1"VGHIER_TSV_WB798"./g'
```

This makes use of the regex directive `|` (escaped with a backslash for `sed`) to indicate an alternative.

Finally, if the word will always be the first item on the line, use the `^` regex to require that:

```
sed -i 's/^VGHIER_TSV_WB798\./"VGHIER_TSV_WB798"./g'
```

And yes, for any of the above, you could have "group"ed and "back-referenced" your string:

```
sed -i 's/^\(VGHIER_TSV_WB798\)\./"\1"./g'
sed -i 's/\([[:space:]]\|[[:punct:]]\)\(VGHIER_TSV_WB798\)\./\1"\2"./g'
```