# Why `sed` with multiple `-e`ends up with error on macOS Monterey?

Tags: sed

On macOS Monterey, why this:

```
$ sed -i -e 's/<azure\/core\/internal\//</g' -e 's/<azure\/core\//</g' -e 's/<azure\/iot\/internal\//</g' -e 's/<azure\/iot\//</g' .
```

… ends up with the following error:

```
sed: -e: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This answers your question [BSD sed vs. GNU sed, and -i](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401905/bsd-sed-vs-gnu-sed-and-i)

Comment: ... specifically, the first `-e` is getting eaten as the backup suffix argument for the `-i` option, causing subsequent `-e`s to be treated as filename arguments

Comment: How would I rewrite this as a single command then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is my solution:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/<azure\/core\/internal\//<azure-sdk-for-c\//g;s/<azure\/core\//<azure-sdk-for-c\//g;s/<azure\/iot\/internal\//<azure-sdk-for-c\//g;s/<azure\/iot\//<azure-sdk-for-c\//g' ./azure-sdk-for-c/*
```

Comment: You could still use multiple `-e` options though, and you can make the substitutions look nicer by using an alternate delimiter: `sed -i '' -e 's,<azure/core/internal/,,g' -e 's,<azure/core/,,g' -e ...`.

Answer (score 4):

Like mentioned in the comments, with the BSD version of sed, `-i` takes a mandatory argument, so in `sed -i -e`, the `-e` becomes that argument, the filename suffix used for backup files. Then, the next argument in your command is `s/<azure\/core\/internal\//</g`, and *since the `-e` or `-f` options weren't seen*, that's the sed script. (This is similar to how both `grep pattern file...` and `grep -e pattern file...` work and do the same.)

The standard behaviour is that options have to appear as the first command line arguments. So after the first non-option, the rest are not interpreted as options, even if they begin with dashes. So `sed` takes them as filenames, starting with the `-e`.

That's also different on GNU, where e.g. `ls dir -l` does the same as `ls -l dir`. But it's not standard, and the BSD sed on mac doesn't support it.
On GNU, `sed foo -e bar` would recognize `-e` as an option, take `bar` as the sed script, and `foo` as a filename. But with the standard interpretation, `foo` would be the script, and `-e` and `-bar` filenames.

---

Fix the issue with `-i`, and the rest falls into place. To use the `-i` option without a backup file on mac, use

```
sed -i '' -e something -e something file...
```

Note that `sed -i.bak` would work with either version of sed to set the backup suffix to `.bak`. (but `sed -i .bak` would not)