# Clearing texts between two specific lines and adding new values in Bash

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am writing a script myself. But I need your help

I have a file as below (test.md):

```
sometext
sometext

<!--SEPERATOR1-->
text to be deleted
foobar to be deleted
foooooooooooobar
foobaaaaaaaaaaar
<!--SEPERATOR1-->

sometext
sometext
```

I want to clean the texts in the sections separated by 'SEPERATOR1' in this text file (test.md) and add new texts. How can I do this, thanks.

Expected output:

```
sometext
sometext

<!--SEPERATOR1-->
new text
butterfly
foo bar etc.
<!--SEPERATOR1-->

sometext
sometext
```

Comment: So what are your attempts?

Comment: @annahri i tried `sed "/pattern/,/pattern/{$!{N; s/pattern/asd/g}}"` but not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sed` specifying a range with `/startpattern/,/endpattern/` with the `c` command to change the text:

```
sed '/<!--SEPERATOR1-->/,/<!--SEPERATOR1-->/c<!--SEPERATOR1-->\nnew text\nbutterfly\nfoo bar etc.\n<!--SEPERATOR1-->' filename.txt
```

Use `\n` for newlines in the result.

You can add `> newfilename.txt` at the end to redirect the output to a file, or add the `-i` flag to change the file in place (though the [exact syntax for this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401905/bsd-sed-vs-gnu-sed-and-i) varies between versions of sed).

But may I also recommend changing `SEPERATOR` to `SEPARATOR` — if someone else with more a "conventional" approach to spelling has to maintain your code later on, which could even be an older version of you, something like that could be very annoying.

Comment: Thanks for helps <3

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'for lines.join("\n") {.subst(:global, / "<!--SEPARATOR1-->" <(.*?)> "<!--SEPARATOR1-->" /, "\nnew text\nbutterfly\nfoo bar etc.\n" ).put};' file.txt

#OR

~$ raku -e 'for lines.join("\n") {.split(/ <?after "<\!--SEPARATOR1-->"> .*? <?before "<\!--SEPARATOR1-->"> /).join("\nnew text\nbutterfly\nfoo bar etc.\n" ).put};'  file.txt
```

Sample Input:

```
sometext
sometext

<!--SEPARATOR1-->
text to be deleted
foobar to be deleted
foooooooooooobar
foobaaaaaaaaaaar
<!--SEPARATOR1-->

sometext
sometext
```

Sample Output:

```
sometext
sometext

<!--SEPARATOR1-->
new text
butterfly
foo bar etc.
<!--SEPARATOR1-->

sometext
sometext
```

The code above is a fairly-conventional approach using Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Briefly (first example), `lines` are read-in, `join`ed with `\n` newlines, and the `SEPARATOR` pattern is searched for (paired), with a `.*?` non-greedy match to zero-or-more characters in between. If found the `<(`…`)>` capture markers drop the match outside of `<(.*?)>`, which gets substituted with the desired lines.

The second example uses a `split`/`join` approach, but is otherwise very similar. Each approach gives the same output.

https://raku.org