# How to pass variable in pattern while using sed command?

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, directory

I have file `abc.sh`

```
search_dir='dummy'
filename='numbers.txt'

for entry in "$search_dir"/*
do
  while read p;
  do 
    sed -i '' "/$p/d" $entry
  done < $filename
done
```

Trying to delete a line with the matching pattern.
Basically, the pattern is just a string which I am passing from the file. 
But unfortunately, it is not working.

What I am able to debug is, I am not passing the variable in pattern correct way.

**EDIT:**
numbers.txt

```
2018061300006178
2018061300006179
2018061300006325
2018061300006326
2018061400006505
```

the content of files that is present in search_dir is :

```
1888~2018061400006505~0101~1~OWNED~SELF EMPLOYED~~~~3~~AGRICULTURE~~~OTHERS~AGRICULTURIST~~~AGRICULTURE~~~~~~~~N~N~Y~N~N~~300000-500000~~~49582E95361D5FA0C10C4C419B2940591C17E94EF329C31047A6B7DE26E68638
1889~2018061400006505~0101~2~OWNED~SELF EMPLOYED~~~~32~~AGRICULTURE~~~OTHERS~AGRIC
```

So numbers.txt contains 2018061400006505  and file also contain numbers related data, so I want to delete the line which matches the given numbers.

Comment: @steeldriver I tried double quotes things but it still not working, I have added the example in the edit section of the question. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Ankur_009 there is a single quote after `-i` in sed. is that a typo?

Comment: @SivaPrasath not the typo, as somewhere i have read that is necessary while using sed cmd. But I have tried without using that too.

Comment: @SivaPrasath this is not duplicate, as I have tried solution mentioned there too.

Comment: @Ankur_009 i hope its not required, can u try this ...`sed -i '/'"$p"'/d'`

Comment: @SivaPrasath that is giving me error "sed: -i may not be used with stdin"

Comment: @SivaPrasath, it doesn't matter one bit if the slashes are single-quoted, double-quoted or not-at-all-quoted. The thing with `-i` is the only issue here, GNU sed wants the backup filename suffix as part of the same argument, so you'd use `-i.bak`, or just `-i` for no backup. BSD sed is different here.

Comment: @ilkkachu can you bit explain.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895/how-can-i-achieve-portability-with-sed-i-in-place-editing

Comment: Note, this question is not *actually* related to passing variables into `sed`, it's about the portability of `sed -i` and/or about working with DOS text files.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the numbers in your example does not contain the delimiter that `sed` is using (by default `/`), the `$p` in your code will be interpreted as a regular expression (with all what that means).

Your code:

```
search_dir='dummy'
filename='numbers.txt'

for entry in "$search_dir"/*
do
  while read p;
  do 
    sed -i '' "/$p/d" $entry
  done < $filename
done
```

Here, you want to delete all lines in the files under `$search_dir` that contains any of the numbers in `$filename`.  Whether this work or not depends on how your `sed` treats `-i ''`.  With some implementations of `sed` you would have to use `-i` without an argument.

Related to `sed -i` and portability: [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895/how-can-i-achieve-portability-with-sed-i-in-place-editing)

It is safer to write the result to a temporary file and then to move that file to the original filename:

```
for entry in "$search_dir"/*
do
  while read p;
  do 
    sed "/$p/d" "$entry" >"$entry.tmp" && mv "$entry.tmp" "$entry"
  done <"$filename"
done
```

This ensures that it will work regardless of what `sed` implementation you happen to be working with. In general, it's a bad idea to try to make in-place changes to files while testing out a script, so you may well want to comment out that `mv` before you are happy with the way the script otherwise works.

This is still a bit unsafe as a general solution though since you're actually "using data as code" (the numbers are data, and you use them a part of your `sed` script). This means that you easily could cause a syntax error in the `sed` script by just inserting a `/` in one of the numbers in your numbers file.

Since the operation is so simple, we may instead use `grep`.  This also gets rid of the inner `while` loop:

```
for entry in "$search_dir"/*
do
  grep -Fv -f "$filename" "$entry" >"$entry.tmp" && mv "$entry.tmp" "$entry"
done
```

This will cause `grep` to read its patterns from `$filename` and to apply these to the `$entry` file.  The `-v` means we'll discard any line containing the pattern and `-F` means `grep` will *not* interpret the numbers as regular expressions but as fixed strings.  With `-f "$filename"` we get `grep` to read the strings from `$filename`.

If there may be directories under `$search_dir` we would want to skip these:

```
for entry in "$search_dir"/*
do
  [ ! -f "$entry" ] && continue
  grep -Fv -f "$filename" "$entry" >"$entry.tmp" && mv "$entry.tmp" "$entry"
done
```

Another, even safer way to do your operation is to use `awk`.  Since with both the `sed` and `grep` solutions above, the number is matched *anywhere* on the line, it is conceivable that we might delete the wrong lines.  With `awk` it's easy to match just the second `~`-delimited field in the data:

```
for entry in "$search_dir"/*; do
    [ ! -f "$entry" ] && continue
    awk -F '~' 'NR==FNR { num[$0]; next } !($2 in num)' "$filename" "$entry" >"$entry.tmp" &&
    mv "$entry.tmp" "$entry"
done
```

The `awk` program first populates an associative array/hash with the numbers as keys, and then prints every line from the `$entry` file whose second `~`-delimited column is not a key in that hash.

Comment: thanks for the detailed info. I appreciate. But  I have tried both the way(grep and sed) , it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ankur_009 Would you mind telling me what actually happens? It's a bit difficult to see your screen from here.

Comment: @Ankur_009 I also added an `awk` variation at the end. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: i have tried the awk it has deleted the line matching with the last string only , line matching with the other number are still there.

Comment: @Ankur_009 Is one or both of your files DOS text files?  In that case run `dos2unix` on them and try again.

Comment: no, one is csv file and other which containing the numbers is txt file.

Comment: @Ankur_009 Were they at any point in time created or edited on a Windows system?

Comment: yes, @Kusalananda

Comment: csv file might be open in windows system, but numbers file is created in linux environment..

Comment: @Ankur_009 Then they may well have trailing carriage return characters at the end of each line. This would confuse `sed`, `grep` and `awk`.  Just run `dos2unix` on the files to make sure they are Unix text files, then try again.

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't help too

Comment: @Ankur_009 <shrug>.  Works for me with the data that you posted.

Comment: I don't know. Will check again tomorrow. Thanks for help.