# how convert linux sed command to bsd

Tags: sed, bsd

How can I make this work on macOS terminal?

```
sed -i 's/config.action_mailer.default_url_options =.*$/config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => "localhost:3000"}/g' config/environments/development.rb
sed: 1: "config/environments/dev ...": command c expects \ followed by text
```

Comment: Related: [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895/how-can-i-achieve-portability-with-sed-i-in-place-editing)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is that the next argument after `-i` is being used as the string to add to a backup copy of the source file. the correct syntax is like:

```
sed -i '.BAK' 'command' file
```

The missing `.BAK` leaves the next argument: `config/…` as the command to execute and sed try (and fail) to execute the `c` command (first letter of `command`).

So, this is an exact duplicate of [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895/how-can-i-achieve-portability-with-sed-i-in-place-editing)