# Sed command writes the expression in outer ifmodule

Tags: sed, syntax

my config file has this

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

I want to change `index.php` to `index.temp`

I created this

```
sed -i -e '/s/index.php/index.temp/‘ dir.conf
```

It makes this,

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
ndex.php/index.temp/
```

Comment: You presumably want to use the `s` substitute command, so do not begin with `/` as `/s/` means match the pattern `s`, and then the command is `i` which inserts the rest of the line.  So use `sed -i -e 's/index.php/index.temp/'`

Answer (score 0):

Your `s///` command is prefixed by a `/` which would make `sed` misunderstand it.  It also looks as if the terminating single quote is not an ordinary single quote (`‘` instead of `'`), but that may be an issue in just this question.

To change all instances of the string `index.php` to `index.temp` in some file `dir.conf`, use

```
sed -i 's/index\.php/index.temp/g' dir.conf
```

The dot in the pattern needs to be escaped as it is special in regular expressions (you could also have used `[.]` in place of `\.`). Also note that this is using `-i` for "in-place editing", which is [not generally portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895).

To make sure that you don't change `myindex.php` into `myindex.temp` or `index.php3` into `index.temp3`, use `\<` and `\>` (or `\b` in place of both) to match the word boundaries:

```
sed -i 's/\<index\.php\>/index.temp/g' dir.conf
```