# How to add a path before the first character of each line in a file.txt and save the same file with those edits?

Tags: text-processing, aix

I have a file that has some lines like:

```
account_1
account_2 
account_3
```

I have to add a path like `/home/info/` before each line and save the same file with those updates like this:

```
/home/info/account_1
/home/info/account_2 
/home/info/account_3
```

How can I handle this on AIX?

Answer (score 3):

To add any string to the start of each line in a file, you may use

```
sed -i 's#^#/home/info/#' file
```

This would do an in-place edit of the file called `file` and would insert  the string `/home/info/` at the start of each line.

On FreeBSD or derivatives (like macOS), you would have to use `-i ''` instead of `-i` (see also "[How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895)").

The `#` are used as delimiters of the `sed` expression here since the replacement text contains `/`.  We could also have written

```
sed -i 's/^/\/home\/info\//' file
```

but that's a bit difficult to both read and write (see Wikipedia: [Leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)).

As always, run `sed` *without* the `-i` option first to make sure that it does the correct thing.

---

For a systems where `sed` does not support `-i` for in-place editing, you will have to write the result to a temporary file and then replace the original with that file:

```
sed 's#^#/home/info/#' <file >file.new &&
mv file.new file
```

This would replace the original file with the modified file if the `sed` command was successful.

If you need to retain meta data such as ownership and file permissions, do it like

```
cp file file.tmp &&
sed 's#^#/home/info/#' <file.tmp >file &&
rm file.tmp
```

Comment: it gave me this issue sed: 

illegal option -- i
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]

Comment: @TarekSayed What Unix are you on?  Are you using busybox?

Comment: @TarekSayed See updated answer.

Comment: AIX devetlpower 1 7 00CAFF374C00

Comment: Good answer; I'll just add 1% by mentioning [Scott's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/117549) that preserves the existing file's link status, owner, and mode: `cp file file.new && sed ... file.new > file && rm file.new`

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks for that, I will incorporate this.

Answer (score 2):

[Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480080/117549) with sed is good; I'll propose an alternative -- an in-place edit with `ed`, which is installed by default on AIX:

```
ed -s input <<< $'1,$s!^!/home/info/!\nw\nq'
```

or more concisely, using `,` as a shortcut for the `1,$` entire-file address range:

```
ed -s input <<< $',s!^!/home/info/!\nw\nq'
```

The idea is otherwise the same as in sed -- use the `s`earch and replace command with a delimiter that is *not* present in the search or replacement text, to avoid LTS; instead of `#` I've arbitrarily chosen `!`. The remaining commands are separated by newlines and instruct `ed` to `w`rite the file back out and to `q`uit out.  The commands are all sent as a here-string to the `ed` command.  I've used the `-s` flag to put `ed` into "script mode", where it quiets the output (bytes read and written, here).

To use here-strings, you'll need to use [ksh93](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/ksh93.htm), also present on stock AIX systems.

Alternatively to here-strings, use `printf`:

```
printf '1,$s!^!/home/info/!
w
q
' | ed -s input
```

Where I've broken the `ed` commands up to multiple lines for legibility, or all in one line:

```
printf '1,$s!^!/home/info/!\nw\nq\n' | ed -s input
```

Alternatively to printf, a here-document works as well:

```
ed -s input << 'EOF'
1,$s!^!/home/info/!
w
q
EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

outra alternativa com awk

```
awk -i inplace  '{ print  "/home/info/"  $1 }'  file

/home/info/account_1
```

- `-i inplace`
  The inplace extension emulates GNU sed’s `-i` option, which performs “in-place” editing of each input file. It uses the bundled inplace.awk include file to invoke the extension properly:
- `print "/home/info/"`
  concatenates the first field.
- $1 represents the first field of the file.

Comment: You need the GNU implementation of `awk`, and a recent version thereof for that though.

Comment: The question wasn't immediately obviously AIX, but [a comment 6 hours previously](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480078/how-to-add-a-path-before-the-first-character-of-each-line-in-a-file-txt-and-save/480115#comment878200_480080) did indicate so, and the question has now been clarified. [AIX'x awk](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/awk.htm) does not yet have the `-i` in-place option.

Comment: awk is updated and contains the -i function normally

Comment: No, it doesn't ([POSIX awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) and [AIX awk](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/awk.htm))

Comment: the result I had was positive and according to the question in question!