# sed inline and extended regex does not work together

Tags: sed, command-line, osx

I am trying to replace an extended regular expression using sed on macOS 10.14.3 (18D109). If I do not use the extended regular expression then the inline flag works otherwise it does not update the file, however without the -i flag it prints the correct result to the console. Why does it happen, How could I fix it?

```
$ echo "foo" > foo.txt
$ sed -i -E 's/fo{1,}/123123/g' ./foo.txt
```

Nothing happens.

```
$ sed -E 's/fo{1,}/123123/g' ./foo.txt
123123
```

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of "nothing happens"? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `sed` to edit a document in-place (with a `sed` implementation that supports this), there will not be any output in the console.  The file will instead be transformed in accordance with the editing script.

```
$ echo "foo" >foo.txt
$ sed -i -E 's/fo{1,}/123123/g' ./foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt
123123
```

On FreeBSD and macOS, the `-i` flag of the provided `sed` implementation has different semantics from what it has with GNU `sed`, and your command would have created a file called `foo.txt-E` as a backup of the original file (and the `-E` option does therefore not take the intended effect).  To use `-i` with *no* backup suffix, do this:

```
sed -i '' -E ...
```

Example on FreeBSD/macOS:

```
$ echo "foo" >foo.txt
$ sed -i '' -E 's/fo{1,}/123123/g' ./foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt
123123
```

Related:

- [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895)