# rotate lines inside file. Move top line to bottom and add date

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

I have a list I want to change from a script. I want to move top entry to bottom so I get a rotating list each time the script is run. I also want to append date to the line that got moved to bottom.
from this. The top folder will be used to store old backups too using rclone.

```
old1
old2
old3
```

to this

```
old2
old3
old1 date time
```

I found a code I tried to use, but it wont move the top entry, just copy it to bottom so I get an output like this

```
old1
old2
old3
old1 date time
old1 date time
```

The code I tried `# Rotate the BACKUPLIST-file, deleting the top entry and adding a new entry at the bottom

OLDEST=$(head -1 $BACKUPLIST | sed 's/ .*//')        # The oldest, extra backup-version
COUNT=$(cat $BACKUPLIST | wc -l)                     # Number of files in list

((COUNT=$COUNT-1))
tail -$COUNT $BACKUPLIST > $BACKUPLIST.tmp
echo $OLDEST $(date) >> $BACKUPLIST.tmp              # Add a new line to the bottom, including today's date`

Comment: You're using `sed 's/ .*//'` to remove an existing date from the first line, right?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little tricky to get the escaping correct in the `date` format string, but given

```
$ cat file
old1
old2
old3
```

then

```
$ cat << 'EOF' | ed -s file
1m$
r !date +\ \%x\ \%X
.-1,.j
,p
EOF
old2
old3
old1 2019-07-25 05:42:32 PM
```

or (as a one-liner)

```
printf '%s\n' '1m$' 'r !date +\ \%x\ \%X' '.-1,.j' ',p' | ed -s file
```

To edit the file in place, replace `p` (print) by `wq` (write-quit). You can replace `%x` and `%X` with other format specifiers of your choice of course.

Comment: heh, I was just working on an ed version. I came up with `printf '%s\n' '1,1m$' "s/$/ $(date "+%F %T")/" wq | ed file`

Comment: @glennjackman hmm yes that might have been simpler

Comment: I find heredocs are more readable for ed commands.

Comment: @prophetse7en, since `ed` is an actual editor, this will be more efficient than reading and re-writing the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ date +"$(head -n 1 file) %F %T" >>file; sed -i 1d file
$ cat file
old2
old3
old1 2019-07-25 23:39:51
```

```
$ date +"$(head -n 1 file) %F %T" >>file; sed -i 1d file
$ cat file
old3
old1 2019-07-25 23:47:10
old2 2019-07-25 23:47:22
```

This inserts the first line of `file` as a string into the output format of `date`.  The `%F` is a shorthand for `%Y-%m-%d` and `%T` is a shorthand for `%H:%M:%S` in most `date` implementations.

The output of `date` is then appended to the end of `file`.

After appending the new data, `sed` is used to delete the old first line (using an in-place edit).  Some `sed` implementation has to be invoked as `sed -i '' 1d file` (see [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895)).

---

The fourth run of the commands above would yield

```
$ date +"$(head -n 1 file) %F %T" >>file; sed -i 1d file
$ cat file
old2 2019-07-25 23:47:22
old3 2019-07-25 23:51:22
old1 2019-07-25 23:47:10 2019-07-25 23:51:24
```

If this is not wanted, use something like

```
awk '{ print $1; exit }'
```

in place of `head -n 1`.  This would pick out the first whitespace-delimited *column* on the first line, but not the full first line with the old date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quickly in bash:

```
mapfile -t lines < file
printf "%s\n" "${lines[@]:1}" "${lines[0]} $(date "+%F %T")" > file
```

Putting that into a function:

```
rotate_file() {
    [[ -w "$1" ]] || return 1
    local -a lines
    mapfile -t lines < "$1"
    printf "%s\n" "${lines[@]:1}" "${lines[0]} $(date "+%F %T")" > "$1"
}
```

A demo:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
$ rotate_file file
$ cat file
2
3
1 2019-07-25 17:16:51
$ rotate_file file
$ cat file
3
1 2019-07-25 17:16:51
2 2019-07-25 17:16:57
```

This slurps the whole file into memory. If the file is large, this can be slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ hd="$(head -1 file)"; tail +2 file; printf '%s %s\n' "$hd" "$(date)"
old2
old3
old1 Thu, Jul 25, 2019  4:27:15 PM

$ hd="$(head -1 file)"; { tail +2 file; printf '%s %s\n' "$hd" "$(date)"; } > tmp && mv tmp file; cat file
old2
old3
old1 Thu, Jul 25, 2019  4:28:44 PM

$ hd="$(head -1 file)"; { tail +2 file; printf '%s %s\n' "$hd" "$(date)"; } > tmp && mv tmp file; cat file
old3
old1 Thu, Jul 25, 2019  4:28:44 PM
old2 Thu, Jul 25, 2019  4:28:46 PM

$ hd="$(head -1 file)"; { tail +2 file; printf '%s %s\n' "$hd" "$(date)"; } > tmp && mv tmp file; cat file
old1 Thu, Jul 25, 2019  4:28:44 PM
old2 Thu, Jul 25, 2019  4:28:46 PM
old3 Thu, Jul 25, 2019  4:28:48 PM
```

Comment: @glennjackman fair enough, I just added the code to do it. Should be pretty self-explanatory.