# sed: -e expression #1, char 10: missing command

Tags: sed

I have seen StackOverflow answers on this question, but I am struggling to see how they apply to my problem because my special characters are escaped and adding a command to the end of the `sed` call does not resolve the problem.

The command syntax I'm using is as follows :

```
sed -i `date +%s` -E 's/^#?master:/master:\n  - serverone\n  - servertwo/' /etc/salt/minion
```

As mentioned, I have already tried adding a command to the end (e.g. `g`) but that has no effect and the same error is presented.

I am using GNU sed 4.7 on Debian 10

Comment: Spot on ! Thank you @steeldriver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When wanting to use a backup suffix with GNU `sed`, the suffix must following the `-i` option immediately, as in

```
sed -i"$( date +.%s )" -E '...as in question...' /etc/salt/minion
```

I've also added a dot to the backup suffix so that you get suffixes like `.1578741576`.

Related:

- [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895)