# Could someone explain to me the syntax of the sed command here?

Tags: sed

I am doing a research project that requires shell scripting, which I have almost no experience in, although I do have some programming experience. Here is the file in question:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=12


read controls
#inlist directory
export MESA_INLIST="/home/nick/mesa-r11701/star/test_suite/rsp_Cepheid_grid/inlist"

sed -i -e 's/.*extra_star_job_inlist2_name.*/extra_star_job_inlist2_name = '"'"''$controls"""'"'/i' $MESA_INLIST
sed -i -e 's/.*extra_controls_inlist2_name.*/extra_controls_inlist2_name = '"'"''$controls"""'"'/i' $MESA_INLIST
```

I am borrowing this file to change the input of this second file `/home/nick/mesa-r11701/star/test_suite/rsp_Cepheid_grid/inlist`. Specifically the `extra_controls_inlist2_name` and the `extra_star_job_inlist2_name` variables (what is after the right side of the equal sign).

```
! this is the master inlist that MESA reads when it starts.

! This file tells MESA to go look elsewhere for its configuration
! info. This makes changing between different inlists easier, by
! allowing you to easily change the name of the file that gets read.

&star_job

      read_extra_star_job_inlist1 = .true.
      extra_star_job_inlist1_name = 'inlist_0all'

      read_extra_star_job_inlist2 = .true.
extra_star_job_inlist2_name = 'inlist_3ms'

/ ! end of star_job namelist


&controls

      read_extra_controls_inlist1 = .true.
      extra_controls_inlist1_name = 'inlist_0all'

      read_extra_controls_inlist2 = .true.
extra_controls_inlist2_name = 'inlist_3ms'

/ ! end of controls namelist


&pgstar

/ ! end of pgstar namelist
```

I am already familiar with what the `export` and `read` commands do. I know that sed is a stream editor that is used for finding and replacing text, which is what my goal with the second file is here. However, what do the `-i -e` options do here exactly? Why are there so many quotes around `$controls$`? What do the `/.*` and the `/i` of the sed command mean? I tried to do a preliminary search for these online, but I could not find an appropriate answer.

Comment: Did you start with `man sed`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller `info sed` in this case, as e.g. `/i` is not explained properly in the GNU `sed` manual, for _whatever_ reason.

Comment: Sure, although the -i and -e would be. I like to see evidence of "searches online" to show self-motivation and the extent of knowledge / where the ignorance starts.

Answer (score 3):

1. `-e` means "the next command line argument is a `sed` expression".
2. `-i` means "do this edit *in-place*, i.e. modify the original file".  This is option is non-standard and may cause confusion when moving between different `sed` implementations on different Unix systems. See e.g. [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895)
3. `/.*` is the start of the regular expression to match the text that is supposed to be substituted.  It's actually `/`, the delimiter for the `s///` (substitution) command in `sed`, and the start of the regular expression `.*extra_star_job_inlist2_name.*`.  The `.*` by itself means "match any number of any character".

   The `.*` also occurs at the end of the expression `.*extra_star_job_inlist2_name.*` and the effect is that any line that contains the string `extra_star_job_inlist2_name` will be replaced entirly (i.e. the substitution would not just affect the string `extra_star_job_inlist2_name` on the line).
4. The `/i` is, again, the `/` delimiter for the `s///` command in `sed` followed by a *flag* for the `s///` command.  This flag is non-standard, only available in the GNU flavor of `sed`.  The flag makes the matching of the expression case-insensitive. See [the GNU `sed` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#index-s-command_002c-option-flags) about this.
5. The weird quotes around `$controls`:

   - The `sed` expression is given in a single quoted string.  Since it's a single quoted string, a variable would not be expanded inside it.  To insert the value of a variable, the single quoted string must first end.  That's the first `'`.
   - Then, apparently, the author of the code wants to insert a literal single quote.  To do that, they quote it: `"'"`.  They could also have used `\'` here.
   - Then follows, for whatever reason, a single quoted empty string, `''`
   - Then comes the value of `$controls` (unquoted).
   - Another empty double quoted string, `""`.
   - Another quoted single quote, `"'"`.
   - And then the `sed` expression continues as a single quoted string.

There are a few issues with the quotes around `$controls`:

1. There are two empty strings.
2. The expansion of `$controls` is unquoted.

A better variation that avoids these issues is

```
sed -i -e "s/.*extra_star_job_inlist2_name.*/extra_star_job_inlist2_name = '$controls'/i" "$MESA_INLIST"
```

i.e. simply use a double quoted string for the whole `sed` expression (and also properly quote `$MESA_INLIST`, which, by the way, does not need to be exported with `export`).  This would work as long as the `sed` expression itself does not contain backslashes or `$` characters (these would need to be escaped as `\\` and `\$`).

Or, to shorten it down a bit, use a capture group to capture the string that you want to repeat in the replacement text,

```
sed -i -e "s/.*\(extra_star_job_inlist2_name\).*/\1 = '$controls'/i" "$MESA_INLIST"
```

(and similarly for the other `sed` command.)

To still use single quotes fore the `sed` expression, you could do

```
sed -i -e 's/.*\(extra_star_job_inlist2_name\).*/\1 = '"'$controls'"'/i' "$MESA_INLIST"
```

Another optimization would be to combine both calls to `sed` into a single call:

```
sed -i -e "s/.*\(extra_star_job_inlist2_name\).*/\1 = '$controls'/i" \
       -e "s/.*\(extra_controls_inlist2_name\).*/\1 = '$controls'/i" "$MESA_INLIST"
```

Comment: ♦ Thank you for this lucid explanation! Please see my upcoming response below to see if I understand correctly.