# How to remove the empty lines in a file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have an output in a file with the blank spaces like

```
daily/A3D05180000052121001 30698

daily/A3D05180000052200001 30698

daily/A3D05180000052203001 30698
```

I need to remove the empty lines and my output should be like

```
daily/A3D05180000052121001 30698
daily/A3D05180000052200001 30698
daily/A3D05180000052203001 30698
```

I tried using **sed**

```
sed -i -e '/./,$!d' -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;ba' -e '}' "$FILESIZE3"
```

But it did not work out...
Can anyone pls help me out on this

Comment: Maybe try `grep -v "^$" $OLDNAME > $NEWNAME`?

Comment: see also [Delete empty lines using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414410/delete-empty-lines-using-sed)

Comment: Are the lines _completely_ empty, or may there be spaces and/or tabs on them?

Comment: @Kusalananda I had some content and i deleted those contents and saved in the file...So the place where i removed the contents empty spaces came

Comment: @clarie Sorry, but that's ever so slightly ambiguous. Are there _spaces_ on the otherwise empty lines? Also, is the file saved with a Windows editor, i.e. is it a DOS text file?

Comment: @clarie If you don't understand what Kusalananda asked you, you can use `cat -E file` to display the file's content in a way that we can see if empty lines are indeed empty or if they have spaces.

Answer (score 8):

```bash
sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' file >file.modified
```

This would delete all lines of `file` that are entirely empty or only contain space-like characters.  Space-like characters would in this context include carriage-return characters found at the end of each line in DOS text files (when processed by Unix tools), tabs, and spaces.  The resulting data would be written to `file.modified`.

Removing the redirection and instead using the `-i` option would do an "in-place" modification of `file` instead of writing to a new file, but be aware that this option is non-portable and may work differently on different Unix systems ([How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895)).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the rest of your `sed` does but isn't this what you're looking for?

```
host:~ # sed -e '/^$/d' file.txt
daily/A3D05180000052121001 30698
daily/A3D05180000052200001 30698
daily/A3D05180000052203001 30698
```

Please clarify the requirement if this doesn't do the trick.

Comment: `sed -i  -e '/^$/d' "$FILESIZE3"` I gave like this...it didn't work. I added -i to edit file inplace...can u help me on this

Answer (score 0):

AWK representation :

```
awk '!/^$/{ print }' infile > outfile && mv outfile infile
```

Answer (score 0):

In vim, I use the global command to remove empty lines. Not sure if it helps in your case.

```
#:[range]g/pattern/cmd
```

The example acts on the specified [range] (default whole file), by executing the command cmd for each line matching pattern (an executing command is one starting with a colon such as :d for delete in vi). In your case it can be

```
:g/^$/d
```

If you have spaces or tabs in between

```
:g/^[\s\t]*$/d
```

Hope it helps.