# Replace the first line with output of a file1 and add content of file 2 to all the files in a folder

Tags: linux, sed

I have a list of files which I would like to bulk edit using sed.

1. Replace the first line of all the files in a directory with output of `header.txt`
2. Amend the output of `footer.txt` to all the files.

Say I have to replace the current XML header on all the files in a folder as below:

From:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

To:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Container xmlns="http://www.arun-test.com/1.0">
  <APIHeader version="2.0" exportTime="Sun Oct 11 09:42:25 EST 2020"></APIHeader>
```

Also I have to add the output of a file `footer.txt` content to all the files in a directory.

Please guide me through the correct steps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed's `r` command to read and insert the header and footer files at addresses `1` and `$` respectively.

Assuming GNU sed (based on your 'linux' tag), and that the number of files in the directory is not large enough to exceed the maximum command length, then

```
sed -i -e '1r header.txt' -e '1d' -e '$r footer.txt' dir/*
```

will add the contents of `header.txt` and `footer.txt` to each file in `dir`.

**Note that `-i` causes the original files to be overwritten** - you would be wise to test it with `-s` in place of `-i` and/or to make backups by changing `-i` to something like `-i.bak`.

Comment: Thanks @steeldrive would also appreciate if there is a BSD sed which I could use on MAC.

Comment: @AArun I *think* that the only part not portable to BSD sed is the use of `-i` **without** a backup suffix. See for example [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895/how-can-i-achieve-portability-with-sed-i-in-place-editing)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove the first line from all files and insert the header, and append the footer at the end, using bash shell:

```bsh
for f in *.xml; do
    tmp=$(mktemp)
    ( 
        cat header.txt
        tail -n +2 "$f"
        cat footer.txt
    ) > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$f"
done
```