# Fill empty cell in pipe-separated-value file with default text

Tags: text-processing, sed, csv

I have a PSV file with empty cells. I want to fill the empty cells with the valule `00000000000`

Example input

```
0000000001|00346743139|201901|07
0000000002||201901|00
```

Desired output

```
0000000001|003467431|201901|07
0000000002|00000000000|201901|00
```

I have tried by using

```
sed -i "s/||/|00000000000|/g" filename
```

Comment: Do you input and output examples have two lines each?

Comment: What happened when you tried your `sed` command? Error messages? Unexpected output? We weren't with you so you need to describe what happened

Comment: Can you check the first line ?
Why `00346743139` should became `003467431` ?
Your sed command is good, the modification is done in place check your file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sed` command appears to be replacing all non-overlapping occurrences of the string `||` with `|00000000000|`.  It is unclear how this does not solve your issue, at least for the data supplied:

```
% sed 's/||/|00000000000|/g' file.csv
0000000001|00346743139|201901|07
0000000002|00000000000|201901|00
```

Note that your expected output seems to truncate `00346743139` into `003467431` (the last two integers are removed).  It is  unclear whether this is intentional.

If there is an issue in using the non-standard `-i` option with the `sed` implementation on your Unix, then please see the post [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895)

For example, on macOS, your command would give you

```
$ sed -i "s/||/|00000000000|/g" filename
sed: 1: "filename": invalid command code f
```

due to the way the `-i` option is used differently on that system.  Use `-i ''` instead on macOS (and read `man sed` on your system about this option).

---

For more robust CSV parsing, you may want to use an actual CSV parser.

Using [the csvkit tools](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to do the CSV parsing, and `jq` to do the actual processing:

```
% csvjson -I -H file.csv | jq -r '.[] | map(select(. == null) |= "00000000000") | @csv' | csvformat -D '|'
0000000001|00346743139|201901|07
0000000002|00000000000|201901|00
```

This first converts your CSV file to JSON using `csvjson`.  The options we use here turns off type inference (so that the numbers are interpreted as strings), and tells the utility that there is no header line in the CSV data. The `csvjson` tool will automatically detect that `|` is the correct delimiter used in the data, but you may also explicitly tell it to use `|` as the delimiter using `-d '|'`.

The `jq` code then replaces all empty values with the string `00000000000` and formats the processed data into CSV again.

Since you want to have pipe-delimited output, `csvformat` is used to change the delimiters outputted by `@csv` in `jq` into `|`-characters.

Redirect the output to a new filename, and then optionally replace the original data with that new file.

Both `csvkit` and `jq` are available for macOS via [the Homebrew package manager](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: *non-overlapping* -> I think you have likely nailed it, since `sed 's/||/|0|/g' <<< '|||'` would give `|0||`, not `|0|0|`. Of course, we can only guess until the asker edits.

Comment: @Quasímodo I think it's more likely that they are on macOS and are having issues with `sed: 1: "filename": invalid command code f` since `-i` works differently from with GNU `sed`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `sed` command looks ok, and it works if I try it with your input example.

As a general alternative for parsing pipe-separated files, or in general table-formatted values, I would recommend `awk`, however. It seems you want to replace "empty" columns with `00000000000`. To do that, you can use

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i=="") $i="00000000000"}} 1' filename
```

- This will first instruct `awk` to consider `|` the field separator for input and output (`FS` is the input field separator, `OFS` is the output field separator.
- It will then iterate over all fields (=columns) of a line, and if it finds an empty field, set its value to `00000000000` instead (`$i` referring to "field nr. `i` of the current line", and `NF` being an auto-generated variable containing the number of fields).
- In the end, it will print all lines including the possible modifications (the seemingly stray `1` at the end)

You can also restrict this easily to only apply to field nr. 2, in case you want to handle other empty columns differently:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {if ($2=="") $2="00000000000"} 1' filename
```

Comment: This seems somewhat overkill when the OP hasn't explained why their (apparently valid) `sed` command isn't sufficient

Comment: @roaima You could say that and I wouldn't really object. However, the OP obviously deals with formatted (though not structured) data, and in these cases using `awk` is almost always better than using `sed`, which is what I wanted to point out (while providing a different approach at solving the OPs task).