# SED ERROR: -bash: sed -i s/ashu/vishu/ test.txt: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, sed, macos

I am accessing a remot HPC through iterm2 in my MacBook Air. Sometime above command works perfectly fine but sometime it gives the error. Can anybody please help me to find out my mistak in it. I am following below format:

```
sed -i 's/search_string/replace_string/' filename

sed -i 's/ashu/vishu/' test.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

The non-standard `-i` option of `sed` on macOS takes a mandatory argument, the filename suffix to use to create backup files.

On macOS, if you want to use in-place editing with *no* backup file, use an empty backup suffix:

```
sed -i '' 's/ashu/vishu/' test.txt
```

However, this would do the wrong thing with GNU `sed`, and it's not clear from your question which `sed` implementation you're ending up using.

To *portably* do an in-place edit, use the following:

```bsh
cp test.txt test.txt.tmp &&
sed 's/ashu/vishu/' <test.txt.tmp >test.txt &&
rm -f test.txt.tmp
```

That is, copy the original file to a temporary name. Then apply the `sed` operation on the temporary named file, redirecting the output to the original file.  Then delete the temporary name.

Using `&&` between the operations as I've done above ensures that one step is not taken unless the previous step has finished successfully.

See also:

- [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895)

Comment: sed -i '' 's/ashu/vishu/' test.txt
sed: can't read s/ashu/vishu/: No such file or directory @kusalananda

Comment: @JatinKashyap Did you use `"` (double quotation mark) or `''` (single quotation marks)?

Comment: @kulfy they are single quotation marks