# AIX - Using Sed To Replace A String In A File

Tags: sed, command, aix, replace, xml

On RHEL, I am able to utilize the *sed -i* command to replace a string within a file, however, on AIX, it seems like the same -i parameter cannot be used.

I have a file called abc.xml that contains the following contents:

```
<test0/>
<test1/>
<config/>
<test2/>
```

I am trying to use the following command:

```
sed -i "s+<config />+<config>3242352353242342424</config>+g" /etc/abc.xml
```

to replace the  parameter within my abc.xml file to:

```
<test0/>
<test1/>
<config>3242352353242342424</config>
<test2/>
```

Is the above possible?

Comment: Instead of using `-i` option, redirect the output of your `sed` to a temporary file and then move that temp file to the original path.

Comment: I've done the following, it seems to be working, does this look correct to you? sed 's+<config/>+<config>3242352353242342424</config>+g' testfile.xml > abc.xml; mv abc.xml testfile.xml

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that your `sed` command works on RedHat as the spacing in the regular expression wouldn't match in the example document that you are showing.  Also, parsing or modifying a document written in a structured document format such as XML is at best hazardous with a line-oriented text editing tool like `sed`.

The second issue is your use of the non-standard `-i` option.  The portable ways of doing in-place editing are described in the Q/A [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895)

Assuming that the XML document is well-formed, you would normally use a command line XML parser to modify the contents of the document.

One such command line XML parser is `xmlstarlet`.

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed -u '//config' -v 3242352353242342424 file.xml
```

This would set the value of all `config` nodes to the string `3242352353242342424` (this value will be properly encoded by `xmlstarlet` if needs be).  Any previous value will be discarded, any attributes to the `config` nodes will be retained.

The modified document would be written to standard output, so you could redirect it into a new file.  There is also an `--inplace` option that you would use after the sub-command `ed` on the command line.

`xmlstarlet` is [known to work](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch01s03.html) on both Linux and AIX.

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift and detailed response, I really appreciate it! I ran the command and received the following output on my AIX 7 machine: bash: xmlstarlet: command not found

Comment: @user435061 Then it's likely available as a 3rd-party package. As I don't know exactly how AIX is managed, I unfortunately can't guide you through an installation of it.

Comment: No problem, I'm restricted on the system I am working on and will not be able to utilize 3rd-party packages. Do you know of any other built-in mechanisms that can be utilized for this?

Comment: @Help you ask the system administrators or your Change Board to install it for you

Answer (score 0):

AIX does not support the `-i` option. You must manually redirect the output.

I recommend not stomping the original file in the same command - just back it up first.

```bash
cp /etc/abc.xml /etc/abc.xml.bak
sed "s+<config />+<config>3242352353242342424</config>+g" /etc/abc.xml.bak \
    > /etc/abc.xml
```

Use [`man sed`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/latest?topic=s-sed-command) to view the options that are available for AIX. There are many other differences in the commands. The s command should work fine though.