# sed possible white space match

Tags: sed, regular-expression, whitespace

I have to modify some paramteres in a param file that may look like:

```
MY_VAR=YES
```

I want to use `sed and came up with this:

`sed -i 's/MY_VAR=[A-Z]*/MY_VAR=NO/' sed.txt` whih seems to work, now I also want it to match if the file looks like

```
MY_VAR = YES
```

or any other whitespace fomatting, how do I do that? I tried `sed -i 's/MY_VAR\s=\s[A-Z]*/MY_VAR=NO/' sed.txt` but that didn't work. How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add wildcard to `\s`. This will cover zero or more spaces. Your command will then be:

```
sed -i 's/MY_VAR\s*=\s*[A-Z]*/MY_VAR=NO/' sed.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems as if the only blanks that you *need* to match are the ones between the variable name and the equal sign.  Whatever comes after the equal sign will be replaced anyway.

Using standard `sed`:

```bsh
sed 's/^\(MY_VAR\)[[:blank:]]*=.*/\1=NO/' params.txt
```

The `[[:blank:]]*` sub-expression will match zero or more blank characters.  A "blank character" is a tab or a space.  The substitution replaces the the whole line that starts with the variable's name followed by optional blanks and a `=` with the variable's name and the string `=NO`.

Testing:

```
$ cat params.txt
MY_VAR=YES
MY_VAR = MAYBE
MY_VAR  =       OK
```

```
$ sed 's/^\(MY_VAR\)[[:blank:]]*=.*/\1=NO/' params.txt
MY_VAR=NO
MY_VAR=NO
MY_VAR=NO
```

For in-place editing of the `params.txt` file, use `-i` correctly depending on what `sed` you use (see [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895)), or use

```
cp params.txt params.txt.tmp &&
sed 's/^\(MY_VAR\)[[:blank:]]*=.*/\1=NO/' params.txt.tmp >params.txt &&
rm -f params.txt.tmp
```