# how to use sed to replace a string of characters in quotes

Tags: sed, string, timestamps, replace

I want to use sed to replace the current time in the code below

```
time0=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
time1=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')

time=$(echo ""$time0"T"$time1"Z")
```

replace $time on first line

```
{
    "X-Apple-I-Client-Time" = "2020-07-08T12:55:08Z";
    "X-Apple-I-Locale" = "en_US";
    "X-Apple-I-MD" = "AAAABQAAABDBy+H0j9QAnYGIzrmKeh9DAAAAAw==";
    "X-Apple-I-MD-M" = "6Q3cWbCm2lI9rrTIyrAsku5zxqO/ZAv9HsW5kHo2thiPqFINp0/OsOz++KS/2vc0ImbI2iMVUbYCZjnS";
    "X-Apple-I-MD-RINFO" = 50660608;
    "X-Apple-I-TimeZone" = "GMT+7";
}
```

Tks All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
now=$(date -u +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
sed 's/\("X-Apple-I-Client-Time" = \).*/\1"'"$now"'";/' file
```

This computes the current UTC timestamp and saves it in the shell variable `now`.
It then finds any line in the file called `file` that contains the exact string `"X-Apple-I-Client-Time" =`  and replaces everything after it with the timestamp in quotes and with a trailing `;`.

The result is written to standard output.  If you want to make the change directly in the original file, you may want to use

```
now=$(date -u +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
cp file file.tmp &&
sed 's/\("X-Apple-I-Client-Time" = \).*/\1"'"$now"'";/' file.tmp >file &&
rm -f file.tmp
```

(This would clobber `file.tmp`)

If your system's `sed` implementation has `-i` for "in-place" edits, then you may obviously use that instead.  Not that `sed -i` on FreeBSD and macOS requires an empty argument to the `-i` option to edit without a backup file (see [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895/how-can-i-achieve-portability-with-sed-i-in-place-editing)).

Answer (score 0):

1. The `Z` at the end of a formatted date means that the time zone is UTC, aka +0000, so you should use `date --utc`, not just `date`.

   It looks like whatever this file is requires `X-Apple-I-Client-Time` to be in UTC, with the actual time zone in `X-Apple-I-TimeZone`.
2. why use `$time0` and `$time1` when `date` can generate the full time with just a single format string (e.g. `+%FT%TZ`. I can't remember if %F and %T are GNU extensions to `date` or not, so you might have to use `'+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'` instead).
3. if you need `$time0` and `$time1` in separate variables, then using command substitution and echo to combine them for `$time` is not only unnecessary, it is probably the worst way you could do it.  Use something like this instead:

   ```
   time="${time0}T${time1}Z"
   ```
4. To insert the timestamp into the file, you could do something like:

   ```
   time=$(date --utc +%FT%TZ)   # or maybe use '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ' instead
   sed -i -e '/X-Apple-I-Client-Time/s/ = "[^"]*"/ = "'"$time"'"/' filename.txt
   ```

   or (if you need `$time0` and `$time1` elsewhere in your script):

   ```
   time0=$(date --utc '+%Y-%m-%d')
   time1=$(date --utc '+%H:%M:%S')

   time="${time0}T${time1}Z"

   sed -i -e '/X-Apple-I-Client-Time/s/ = "[^"]*"/ = "'"$time"'"/' filename.txt
   ```
5. Personally, I'd avoid using a variable called `$time` because it's the same as the built-in `time` command and `/usr/bin/time`.   Accidentally adding a space before the `=` in an assignment (like `time = "${time0}T${time1}Z" instead of` time="${time0}T${time1}Z"`) will run the` time` command instead.

   I'd probably use `$t` if it was a one-use throwaway variable, or something more descriptive and a little longer otherwise.