# Remove one single character after a comma

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file (approx. 300'000 lines) with a unique column exhibiting 2 to 6 fields separated by a comma.

```
A,BB,CC  
EF,GHI,DKLM,OP          
Q,RS,TUV 
W,XY
```

What I would I like to achieve:

```
A,B,C  
EF,HI,KLM,P         
Q,S,UV 
W,Y
```

Said differently, I would like to remove in each line, the FIRST character after each comma.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.
Best regards,

Laurent

Comment: Can there ever be an "empty" field in this (apparently) CSV file, as in `A,,CC`?.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat file
A,BB,CC
EF,GHI,DKLM,OP
Q,RS,TUV
W,XY
```

```
$ sed 's/,./,/g' file
A,B,C
EF,HI,KLM,P
Q,S,UV
W,Y
```

The regular expression `,.` matches a literal comma followed by any other character whatsoever.  The `sed` expression `s/,./,/g`  substitutes each comma and the following character with just a single comma, effectively removing that other character.  The substitution is carried out for each non-overlapping match on every line.

Redirect the output to a new file, or use `sed` with `-i` in an appropriate way (see [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895)).

Comment: Dear Kusalananda. Thanks for your response, I appreciate that you took some of your time to help me. I have a question following your post. What do you mean by "The substitution is carried out for each non-overlapping match on every line"? If in a same line, I have twice the same substitution, for instance [,X] and later on the same line [,X], it will not work?

Comment: @Opus_francigenum In your example, there is never any problem since all occurrences of `,X` are non-overlapping.  If you had `,,X`, then the second comma would be removed, not the `X`.  This is because in `,,X`, the two substrings `,,` and `,X` are _overlapping_.  If you have cases like this and want to avoid removing commas, then use `s/,[^,]/,/g` instead as the `sed` expression.  This changes the meaning from "change any comma and the following character with a comma" to "replace any comma and the following non-comma with a comma".

Comment: Crystal clear. Many thanks Kusalananda for your time ... and patience :-) Best regards to you.

Comment: @Opus_francigenum Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.