# Invalid command code . - Using sed to replace characters inline

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I'm fairly new to working with bash / shell scripts so please excuse me if this is really simple. I am trying to replace inline a file that is nested in a directory, however I receive

```
Invalid command code .
```

when I try

```
sed -i 's/\([^.]*\).css/\1.min.css/g' ./bobby/templates/layout.html;
```

I have a big hunch it's `./bobby/templates/layout.html` that's throwing the error, but I'm unsure how to reformat this to be a valid filepath.

Comment: Are you on OSX? The sed command seems to have a quirk there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573368/in-place-edits-with-sed-on-os-x

Comment: This is probably handled by [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92895)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like your version of `sed` requires a suffix argument for the `-i` option.  That means it's probably on a Mac or FreeBSD machine.

`sed` is then interpreting your sed script as the suffix, and the filename as the sed script....hence the error message `Invalid command code .`, because that's the first character of the filename.

Try:

```
sed -i .bak 's/\([^.]*\)\.css/\1.min.css/g' ./bobby/templates/layout.html
```

I've added a backslash to escape the `.` in the LHS of the s/// command (otherwise it will match *any* character, not just a literal `.`), and got rid of the `;` at the end of the filename - that would only be needed if there was more than one command in the same line.

The sed script will do an in-place edit of the file, and make a backup as `.../layout.html.bak`

Alternatively, you can do it with perl.  e.g.

```
perl -i -p -e 's/([^.]*)\.css/$1.min.css/g' ./bobby/templates/layout.html
```

BTW, the regular expressions used in both the sed and perl versions may change more than you expect, because it's unlikely that there will be just `filename.css` on a line by itself in a `.html` file.  I'd test it first without the `-i` option.

You may want something more like `s:(/[^.]*)\.css:$1.min.css:g`, so that it only changes a filename if it's immediately preceded by a slash character.  It's impossible to be more specific than that without seeing what your actual input file looks like.

Comment: I appreciate the thorough answer. And yes I am using a Mac.

Comment: For correct answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42667816/1368703

Comment: @Wyrmwood how, exactly, is that any more "correct" than what I wrote? It's the same answer ("sed on mac requires an arg for the -i option") in slightly different words.

Comment: On MACOS adding '' after the -i worked for me. Not sure why. Seemingly the MAC version of sed is the BSD version. still means nothing to me, but it worked. :)

Comment: @cas, I did not understand your answer the linked answer helped and then I understood your answer a little more. I assume all that is required to be said is that -i requires a zero length argument??? I up voted your answer as ultimately it helped and had content.