# Is it possible to use options -i and -E simultaneously in sed?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, macos

I have a file like

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String PACKAGE_VERSION = '1.24.0.1';
}
```

I am executing the script

```
sed -E "/PACKAGE_VERSION/s/\'([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\'/\'1.24.0.2\'/g" force-app/main/default/classes/Constants.cls > temp.cls
mv temp.cls force-app/main/default/classes/Constants.cls
```

to replace the string '1.24.0.1' with '1.24.0.2'

Is this possible to do this with one line? Should I use `awk` instead of `sed` to inline edit the file?

When I try to execute a command

```
sed -iE "/PACKAGE_VERSION/s/\'([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\'/\'1.24.0.3\'/g" force-app/main/default/classes/Constants.cls
```

file Constants.clsE is created instead of inline modification to the current file and the new file doesn't have substitution.

When I try to execute a command

```
sed -Ei "/PACKAGE_VERSION/s/\'([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\'/\'1.24.0.3\'/g" force-app/main/default/classes/Constants.cls
```

I receive an error

```
sed: 1: "force-app/main/default/ ...": invalid command code f
```

I want the script to work both in MacOS and Linux without changing the script.

I tried to use `awk`, but I don't understand how can I make it inline editing the file?

When I try to execute the following

```
awk -v v="$version" '/PACKAGE_VERSION/{gsub(/[0-9]+(.[0-9]+){3}/,v)}1' force-app/main/default/classes/Constants.cls > force-app/main/default/classes/Constants.cls
```

this makes my file blank

Comment: I am not sure, I want this to work both on my machine (MacOS) and CI server (Linux).

Comment: @steeldriver, note that it's not *BSD sed*, its *FreeBSD sed* (as found on macos as well). Other BSDs (NetBSD and OpenBSD at least), eventually went the GNU way in this instance when they added a `-i` option to their `sed` years after FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-iE` means to backup the file using the extension `"E"`. You have to use:

```
sed -i.old -E ...
```

to backup file `filename` to `filename.old`.

---

After reading comments and the update with your environment (macOS), I add a couple of links where you can find useful information about `sed` usage with `-i`:

- [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895/how-can-i-achieve-portability-with-sed-i-in-place-editing)
- [sed in-place flag that works both on Mac (BSD) and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux)

---

Also if you want to replace the version, probably it's more readable with `awk`:

```
awk -v v='1.24.0.2' '
  /PACKAGE_VERSION/{gsub(/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}/,v)}1
' force-app/main/default/classes/Constants.cls > file.tmp &&
  mv file.tmp force-app/main/default/classes/Constants.cls
```

Note: You cannot use the input file as the destination as it would be truncated, that's what you mention at the end of your post. A temporary file is used for help.

In general, I prefer using a temporary file, when using `awk` or `sed` rather than their in-place option (for GNU `awk`). The above command is expected to work for both your environments.

Comment: can I make sed edit inline this file without making backup or suffix but using extended regex so far the substitution takes place?

Comment: In FreeBSD / macos, to not backup, you need `sed -Ei '' 'sed-code' file...`. While it's `sed -Ei 'sed-code' file...` with GNU/busybox/netbsd/openbsd `sed`. You can't conciliate them, but you could use `perl -pi -e ...` where those `sed`s borrowed `-i` from.

Comment: The point is that for GNU-like `sed`, the `-i` option takes an optional argument (which has to be affixed to the option) while for FreeBSD / macOS, the argument is required and may or may not be affixed (except you can't affix an empty string)

Answer (score 4):

In some seds (at least [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1) and the one you get on Macs), the `-i` option takes a *mandatory* argument that sets a suffix to use for backup files. You'd write `-i.suffix`, or `-i .suffix` in the shell, or `-i ""` to give no suffix. In those, either `-iE` or `-i -E` would take `E` or `-E` as the argument to `-i` and not an option.

In some other seds (at least [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html#Command_002dLine-Options) and Busybox), the `-i` option takes an *optional* argument for the suffix, such that anything after it in the same command line argument string is the suffix. It's usually presented as `-i[suffix]` in documentation. You'd write `-i.suffix` in the shell, or just `-i` to give no suffix. In those `-iE` would still make `E` the suffix, but `-i -E` would work as two options.

In both, `-iE` means to use the suffix `E`, and in the FreeBSD/Mac one, `-Ei ...` takes the following argument as the suffix (the one where you put your sed program in the question).

Those two ways are incompatible if you want to give the empty suffix for no backup file. In that case you'll have to know the difference and use `-i "" -E` with the FreeBSD/Mac one, or `-i -E` with the GNU one.

Or, if you want a backup file or don't care, just use `-i.bak -E` in either. (you can always just delete the backup file later.)

See also [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92895/170373)

Answer (score 4):

Different implementations of `sed` copied the `-i` option of `perl` for in-place editing, but unfortunately with a different API between themselves.

Some also added a `-E` or `-r` for support to the (superior) extended regexps (POSIX ones or variants thereof), some `-R` or `-P` for the even (immensely) superior perl-like regexps (PCRE or similar), but again (apart for `-E` that will make it to the next version of the POSIX standard and is found on more and more implementations these days), nothing universal.

Here, you might as well use the real thing and avoid all those portability problems:

```
perl -i -pe "s{\bPACKAGE_VERSION\s*=\s*\K'\d+(\.\d+){3}'}{'1.24.0.3'}g" file
```

Comment: there was another answer providing solution with awk, do you know how can I use that? I don't have perl either in my machine nor in the CI

Comment: @Patlatus, there are even fewer `awk` implementations that support in-place editing. To my knowledge, it's only GNU `awk` with its `-i inplace` option.

Comment: @Patlatus, do you mean macos no longer ships with `perl` by default!?

Comment: I want this script to be run both in my local machine and CI runner host, I think `perl` is not available there

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this as follows.
For macOS the variable is set to nonempty value & for others an empty value. Then the shell expansion will expand to a quoted empty value in case of macOS and nothing otherwise (Linux machines)

```bash
os=$(case $(uname) in Darwin*)  echo x;; esac)
sed -Ei ${os:+""} -e "..." file
```

---