# Using "sed" with "-i" option creates strangely-named new file while leaving the input file untouched

Tags: sed, command-line, macos

I have this command:

```
sed -i 's/^CREATE DATABASE.*$//' world.sql
```

If I run that, it says:

```
sed: -I or -i may not be used with stdin
```

and creates a new file called `orld.sql`. The original file still exists afterwards.

So I guess, `sed` sees `world.sql` as a `w orld.sql` command? 
How can I prevent that behaviour?

[This is on macOS.]

Comment: Related: [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895/how-can-i-achieve-portability-with-sed-i-in-place-editing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, `sed` on MacOS is the FreeBSD flavor which *requires* a backup suffix to be supplied when using the `-i` option. The error message you get implies that it mis-interpreted parts of your command because you used the option without providing one.

So, try it with

```
sed -i".backup" 's/^CREATE DATABASE.*$//' world.sql
```

which will create a `world.sql.backup` and otherwise perform the in-place edit of `world.sql`.

*Some* `sed` versions may accept an empty backup suffix, as in `sed -i ''`, which will prevent creation of a backup file, but you would need to look it up in the documentation for the specific version you are using. See

- [sed command with -i option failing on Mac, but works on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247319)
- [How can I achieve portability with sed -i (in-place editing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92895/80216)

for more insight

Answer (score 3):

We need to dig into what your command line means to `sed`

> ```
> sed -i 's/^CREATE DATABASE.*$//' world.sql
> ```

The syntax of macOS sed invocation is:

```
sed -i 'suffix' 'command(s)' filename(s)
```

The suffix is mandatory for the `-i` option. 
If the suffix is null, there must be at least one space
between `-i` and the suffix, as in `-i ''`. 
This is is for macOS sed as is your case.

In the case of GNU `sed` there should be no space
between `-i` and the suffix, like `-i''`.

- So the strange looking string `s/^CREATE DATABASE.*//` is the suffix appended to the filename for saving the backup.
- As you guessed,
  your intended filename `world.sql` becomes the sed command to be applied.

- And since you didn't use the -e option so only one command was being expected.
  Of course, one can supply more by separating them with semicolon
  and quoting the argument. But this doesn't concern us here.
- As you guessed, `w` happens to be a valid sed command
  to write the pattern space to the file
  whose name is whatever follows the `w` till the end of the command.
- And so sed creates a file named `orld.sql` in preparation for filling it up during the execution phase.
- And now nothing remains on the command line, so sed thinks the data is to come from the stdin. Hence you see that message from sed that in `-i` mode you can't take data from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the magic paramater `--` to tell most versions of `sed` (as well as many other CLI tools) that you are done giving it switches (which generally start with `-` or `--`) and the remainder of the command line should be parsed as arguments.  As such:

```
$ sed --in-place 's/^CREATE DATABASE.*$//' -- world.sql
```

Using the substitution command in this place where you are removing the entire line might, though, be more succinctly done with:

```
$ sed --in-place '/^CREATE DATABASE/d'
```

Your question also is tagged with MacOS.  Macs use the BSD versions of some tools such as `sed` rather than the version usually included in Linux, and requires an actual parameter for `--in-place`.  However, this parameter, if an empty string, behaves as it does on other POSIXes:

```
$ sed --in-place '' '/^CREATE DATABASE/d'
```

Comment: If I use `--`, I get `sed: illegal option -- -
usage: sed script [-Ealnru] [-i extension] [file ...]
 sed [-Ealnu] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]`...